# Узаконим гольф?

Tags: предложение, тематика, правила

Коллеги, у нас часто попадаются вопросы, которые достаточно просты сами по себе, но на которых можно продемонстрировать продвинутую технику на каком-нибудь из языков, нестандартные подходы и экзотические, но полезные языки.

Ответы на такие вопросы обычно интересны всем и встречают оживлённую реакцию если не всего сообщества, то по крайней мере активной его части.

Пример такого вопроса недавно бурно обсуждался в чате:

- [Дан алгоритм (формула), сделайте на любом языке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515861/10105)

Среди участников сайта на данный момент нет консенсуса по поводу того, хотим ли мы видеть подобные вопросы на сайте, и того, как к ним относиться.

Предлагаю подобные вопросы официально разрешить. Они не вредят сайту, не противоречат правилам, создают полезное разнообразие, вносят живую струю в общий поток вопросов, и позволяют узнать неожиданные вещи другим участникам.

Возможно, такие вопросы будут требовать повышенного внимания модераторов, но в этом я покамест не вижу большой проблемы.

Comment: Поддерживаю, но нужно сформулировать четко правила и выделить метку. Как с [tag:инспекция-кода]

Comment: Т.е. принятых ответов там, скорее всего не будет?

Comment: @edem: Зависит от автора вопроса. Но если ответов много, всё равно _большинство_ ответов принято не будет.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ тут можно посмотреть по каким правилам они принимают/не принимают вопросы, а так идея добавляет уже спортивного интереса, конечно.

Comment: @Nofate, и кто же будет эту метку ставить?

Comment: @Qwertiy у нас пока свобода (относительная) в развешивании меток.

Comment: Вот такой вопрос - прекрасный пример для "гольфа", не находите? ;-) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517070

Comment: @KromStern, code golf как форма протеста? )

Comment: @KromStern, находим. Попозже нашаманю :)

Comment: @edem, подозреваю, что лучше тут: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info Впрочем, правила для гольфа тоже иногда в тему :)

Comment: @KromStern, [Примерная идея](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517092/178988). Осталось ещё немного подумать и переписать на плюсы.

Comment: По сути, любой вопрос можно воспринимать как "гольф". Есть на него ответ и ты знаешь лучше и короче, то почему бы и не написать его, даже если там этот ответ принят.

Comment: @edem: Да, но это ведь хорошо?

Comment: @VladD скажем так, если вопросы "гольф" и вопросы "сделай мою лабу" будут чётко различать, и не поощрать вторые, под видом первых, то "гольф" вопросы имеют смысл.

Comment: @edem: Я здесь согласен с точкой зрения Qwertiy: гольфовые решения невозможно сдать преподавателю. Ну и мне кажется, неинтересные codegolf-вопросы быстро заминусуются.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## Да

Такие вопросы нужны, интересны, и мы хотим видеть их на нашем сайте.

Comment: +2 за 6 секунд - круто)))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Дааа :) Посмотрим, за сколько придут минусы внизу.

Comment: утром — правила, вечером — голосование. или вечером — правила, а на другой день утром — голосование.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: А в чём проблема? Что поменяют _точные_ правила?

Comment: @VladD, они определят *точные* критерии — является ли вопрос полезным или подлежит закрытию/удалению.

Comment: нужно обратить внимание, что вопросам-турнирам на [codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  рекомендуется [следовать заданному шаблону](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/template-for-challenges) и более того рекомендуется сначала [опубликовать соревнование на Мете-песочнице](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140), чтобы отточить формулировку.

Answer (score 15):

Как "гольф" будет сосуществовать с народно-нелюбимыми вопросами типа ("вот условие, сделайте за меня домашку!!!") ?

- [Напишите программу, которая по полному списку выдаст этот список в сокращенном виде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517070)
- [Как решить учебное задание?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/355693)
- [Найти частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда с факториалом: sum (-1)^k (k + 1) / k!, k=0..n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515861)
- [По данному натуральному N вычислите сумму выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484987)
- [Контрольная по Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207763)

Comment: Кстати да, нерадивые студенты могут замаскировать под "гольф" свои "лабы".

Comment: @edem, но ведь получат-то они гольф, который сдать не смогут. Это не проблема. Минутку, вспомню, как постить ответ на закрытый вопрос...

Comment: @Qwertiy так в чем же отличия гольфа от выполнения чужой домашки?

Comment: @KromStern, предлагаю переоткрыть [сумму квадратов](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484987/178988): ```for(;alert("2".repeat(n-1).split``.reduce((r,x)=>r.push(+r.slice(-1)+ +x)&&r,[1]).reduce((r,x)=>r.push(+r.slice(-1)+ +x)&&r,[0]).reduce((r,x)=>r+x)););``` На 128 работает. Кстати, можно и поинтереснее for использовать. После переоткрытия покажу :)

Comment: @Qwertiy не увлекайтесь, это чужой вопрос с чужой проблемой. Не надо брать в руки "молоток" и переделывать все вопросы в "гвозди" )

Comment: Ну, не вижу проблем. Если вопрос задан как «гольфовый», то он не мешает другим вопросам. Если вопрос не задан как «гольфовый», лишние ответы на него автору вопроса тоже не помешают.

Comment: Если вопрос задан как гольфовый, то он размывает тематику сайта. Если как негольфовый, то ответы на него поощряют задание таких же вопросов и способствуют скатыванию сайта в УГ. **К теме** - так в чем отличие домашек от гольфа?

Comment: @KromStern, вопрос заброшен, ответ на него всё равно никому не нужен. Разница в том, что если ты сможешь объяснить преподавателю, как работает гольфированный код, то непонятно, зачем ты вообще просил решить домашку за тебя, т. к. мог бы сам за 5 минут.

Comment: @KromStern, ответ про интервалы готов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517092/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy считайте что вы меня убедили. Ловите плюс )

Comment: @Зонтик [для ознакомления](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-1-phenomenon)

Answer (score 10):

Господа товарищи, предлагаю найти или придумать самим, для словосочетания "гольф-вопрос" более адекватное название. В текущем же варианте "гольф-вопрос" воспринимается примерно как "борьба-ответ".

Для стран западного мира, да и вообще для тех стран, где распространена игра в гольф, значение слов "гольф-код" интуитивно понятно - это код с **наименьшим** количеством символов, по аналогии с правилами этой игры, закатить мяч в лунку за **наименьшее** количество шагов.

В России же, например, эта игра не особо популярна, поэтому "гольф-код" и воспринимается как бессмыслица, что описано во вступлении. Поэтому можно вспомнить какие-либо виды спорта, соревнований и т.п, где условием победы является наименьшее количество шагов чего-то там. И на основании этих названий сформировать свой вариант именования для данного "кода". Также можно и не делать упор на видах спорта в принципе, а выбрать совсем другой подход для наименования.

Кроме того, даже на самом codegolf'е поднимался вопрос о его переименовании. Критерием победы не всегда является наименьшее количество символов, поэтому имеет смысл выбрать другое сочетание, отражающее, что вопрос является неким соревнованием. На мой взгляд, поскольку это всё-таки не специализированный golf-сайт, критерием будет чаще являться оригинальность идеи или реализации, а не длина.

Варианты предлагайте в комментариях и там же голосуйте за наиболее достойного "участника".

Comment: я уже писал [tag:флуд-код]

Comment: [tag:шаманим-с-кодом] Заодно отражает, что критерии не совсем гольфа - символы же мы не считаем, и минифицировать не требуется - смысл скорее в идее :)

Comment: [tag:химичим-с-кодом] - пожалуй, так лучше; но заменять прошлый вариант не хочется)))

Comment: "**лакод**" - от "лаконичный код"

Comment: как кто-то сказал "форма протеста" `г...о-код`

Comment: В комментарии к другому ответу @jfs упомянул [tag:вопрос-турнир].

Comment: Надо бы перетащить варианты из чата - там много интересных.

Comment: Раз тут внезапное голосование в голосовании - варианты из чата:

Comment: [tag:внезапный-codegolf] от @VladD

Comment: [tag:подземелья-и-программы] от @Nofate

Comment: [tag:техномагия] от @Grundy

Comment: [tag:кодофокус] от @Grundy

Comment: [tag:гольф-код] от @D-side

Comment: [tag:кодомагия]

Comment: @Qwertiy если критерием победы будет оригинальность, то тогда вообще беда будет: что для одного оригинально, то для другого банально, а символы то хоть подсчитать можно объективно.

Comment: @edem, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info

Comment: Внезапно, 7 декабря 2015 года я уже создавал метку [tag:код-гольф] =)

Comment: Ещё очевидный вариант: [tag:соревнование].

Comment: @edem: Перенёс варианты для голосования в отдельный вопрос: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2958/10105

Answer (score 0):

## Нет

Такие вопросы не нужны, они отвлекают, мешают нормальному процессу сбора знаний, мы не хотим видеть подобные вопросы на нашем сайте.

Comment: В данной формулировке вопроса, точноее его отсутствия, единственный ответ "Нет", и он правильный. Есть более удачные примеры гольфа, когда требуется проверить на каком языке будет выполняться быстрее, или на каком языке получится более компактный код или самый легкий файл после компиляции. А предложение "напиши на любимио языке" вызывает только ... В общем, ничего хорошего.
Мое предложение, исправить формулировку вопроса на: "Разрешить посты по поиску самых-самых, которые должны быть выражены в вопросительной и только вопросительной форме?"

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov; Ваше мнение понятно. Вот для учёта всех мнений у нас и предназначены голосования.

Comment: достаточно того, что я тут апнул или есть еще места, нде можно поголосовать?
Этот вопрос насущный. Существуют такие форумы, а особенно импортные, где лучше молчать, чем лишнего сказать, а за неудачный "гольф" и в бан пошлют - не моргнут. "На русском" очень демократичный.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov: На текущий момент это единственное голосование о _допустимости_ на сайте подобных вопросов. Если мы договоримся, что гольф допустим (покамест голосов «за» больше), то за это банить не будут. Банят у нас за спам, злостный неоднократный офтопик и неадекватное поведение, за вопросы «немного не по теме» вроде не банят.

Comment: Только за. Я просто предлагаю формулировку, чтобы все вопросы были вопросами, а не задачками из Когана или Перельмана.