# Метка для гольф-вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, создание-метки

Коллеги, на текущий момент простые вопросы, предполагающие многочисленные конкурирующие ответы, и соревнующиеся в качестве таких ответов, прошли через опрос ([Узаконим гольф?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/10105)), и приняты со счётом 23:2. Сейчас мы по аналогии с англоязычным сайтом называем такие вопросы *code golf*.

Давайте попробуем теперь придумать подходящую метку для таких вопросов.

Я думаю, имеет смысл оставить точные критерии оценки на усмотрение авторов вопросов (не обязательно «наименьшее количество символов»), поэтому метка не обязательно должна базироваться на слове «гольф».

Просьба проголосовать за варианты названия метки.

Comment: Так как вопросы могут быть непосредственно "гольфовые" и не-"гольфовые" (соревновательного типа), поэтому имеет смысл из этого голосования выбрать **двух** победителей: первую метку "гольфовую", а вторую метку не-"гольфовую".

Comment: Отсюда предложение: в вариантах для голосования уточнить в какой номинации участвует данный претендент. Например вариант "**лакод**" предлагался в качестве альтернативы "гольф", но он не будет подходить для вопросов не-"гольфового" типа, там уже лучше использовать метку "вопрос-турнир", просто "турнир" или "соревнование".

Comment: Внезапно, варианты, тысячи их.

Comment: Сделайте ответы общими, а то тут такое дело http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2981/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @edem: Готово, сделал!

Comment: По ответам можно заметить, что метка выбирается вовсе **не для гольфа**, я для **вопросов соревновательного характера**. Кроме гольфа есть множество жанров, [вот список с PPCG](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/908/48189), например. Голосование, по-хорошему, надо бы запустить заново, объяснив ситуацию, но похоже. что сообщество уже выявило реальный смысл обсуждаемого понятия и результаты отличаться не будут.

Comment: @D-side: Да, я тоже так думаю. Так что побеждающая на текущий момент метка «соревнование» выглядит правильно.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) от [@VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9340_2938).

> Вопрос, содержащий интеллектуальное соревнование, в котором участники должны реализовать поставленную задачу, следуя некоторым условиям, например наименьшим числом байт программного кода (так называемый "код-гольф", "code golf"). Могут присутствовать ограничения на используемый язык, обычно применяются некоторые правила «честной игры».
>
> Эта метка объединяет вопросы, аналогичные тематике сайта http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Переименовал метку, синонимизировал к ней код-гольф, подправил краткое описание, сделал общее. Вроде бы всё на этом, пора задавать новые вопросы-соревнования!

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

[вопрос-турнир](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80) от [@jfs](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9280_2934).

Comment: Не слишком ли это широко? Насколько я понимаю суть гольфа, там важно именно минимальную программу написать. Турнир может иметь и другие правила.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Насколько я понимаю, суть в том, чтобы не ограничиваться критерием «минимальное число символов». Самый быстрый/самый изящный/самый популярный (больше всего голосов)/самый непонятный/что угодно. В исходном вопросе (http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/10105) говорилось именно о расширенной точке зрения.

Comment: тогда это слишком нечеткие критерии конкурса, слишком субъективные. Неясно, к чему стремиться. Считаю, что условия должны быть максимально четкими.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Моё предложение — критерии должны оговариваться автором вопроса в самом вопросе. Если критерии плохие, вопрос заминусуют. И поделом!

Comment: Тогда правила для самих вопросов стоит прописать тщательно. И про песочницу отличное предложение

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Разумеется! Сейчас всё находится в процессе разработки.

Comment: турнир подразумеает победителя. а кодгольф - нет :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Почему кодгольф нет? Самый короткий ответ = победитель в традиционном кодгольфе. По-моему, так.

Comment: Именно самый короткий? Или самый быстрый/изящный/популярный/что угодно? IMO,  гольфе важен сам процесс, а не факт победы :)

Comment: @PashaPash популярность ответа может меняться со временем

Answer (score 5):

[код-гольф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84) от @NickVolynkin

Answer (score 3):

[химичим-с-кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc) от [@Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9278_2938).

Answer (score 3):

[подземелья-и-программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) от [@Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9295_2938).

Answer (score 2):

[кодофокус](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81) от [@Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9297_2938).

Answer (score 2):

[гольф-код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) от [@D-side](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9298_2938).

Answer (score 2):

[внезапный-codegolf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-codegolf) от [@VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9294_2938).

Answer (score 2):

[кодомагия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f) от [@Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9305_2938).

Answer (score 1):

[флуд-код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) от [@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9276_2938).

Answer (score 1):

[лакод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) (лаконичная форма словосочетания «лаконичный код») от [@edem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9279_2938).

Answer (score 0):

[техномагия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f) от [@Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9296_2938).

Answer (score 0):

[конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81). Оказывается, такая метка уже существует, создана [@Spectre](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/127037/2) в 2012 году

Comment: Учитывая, что на ХК была возможность напрямую делиться репой, мне кажется, это была попытка реализации bounty.

Comment: @Nofate: В любом случае нужно будет что-то сделать, а то метка ставится на новые вопросы.

Comment: @VladD, синонимизировать когда определимся. Пусть пока ставится.

Answer (score -9):

[г...о-код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3...%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) от [@Sergey](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84#comment9283_2938).