# Выборочное обнуление голосов

Tags: дефект, ответы, голосование

[Метка для гольф-вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2958/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2) - вот тут голосую по всем вариантам +/-, затем через некоторое время (пару дней), когда захожу в эту тему, то вижу что мои голоса "сброшены" почти у всех, кроме пары тройки ответов. Данное обнуление голосов произошло уже два раза. С чем это связано, какие-то лимиты?

Comment: Поскольку все варианты ответа от @VladD, система могла уличить вас в массовом плюсо-минусовании.

Comment: Проверил - откатов голосов у вас не было. К тому же, если бы был - откатились бы голоса за все варианты (при условии, что вы их одновременно ставили). А пропали только голоса за или в обе стороны?

Comment: @NickVolynkin сейчас опять произошло обнуление (уже третий раз), из 13 голосов, на данный момент только 3 сохранилось, возможно связано с тем, что вопросы стали общими, но не думаю. Голоса обнулились и за и против.

Comment: @edem очень странно. Буду за десктопом- посмотрю ещё раз.