# Код-гольф или любое другое соревнование - это не конкурс

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, конкурс, термины, соревнование

Последнее время очень часто вижу здесь слово "конкурс" в контексте [вопросов-соревнований](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2958/176217). Предлагаю не называть вопросы-соревнования "конкурсами", т.к. на сайте уже [есть функционал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) с соответствующим названием, дабы не вносить путаницу.

**Код-гольф или любой другой вопрос, попадающий под действие метки [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) - соревнование. Но не конкурс!**

При этом на вопросе-соревновании, конечно же, может быть дополнительно объявлен конкурс, как это позволяет движок, не ранее, чем через 2 дня с момента публикации вопроса.

Comment: У нас нв физкультуре сегодня был гольф-код))))

Comment: Любой код-гольф — соревнование, но не любое соревнование — код-гольф. Как раз таки пресловутые «конкурсы-анимации» не являются код-гольфом. Это я к тому, что вы в своем посте поставили знак равенства между код-гольфом и соревнованием.

Comment: @eanmos где вы увидели знак равенства?

Comment: Люто плюсую, в последних обсуждениях соревнований по анимации - постоянные проблемы из-за пересечения этих терминов.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну не буквально, конечно, поставили, но вот это: «Код-гольф (соревнование)» читается именно так. И вообще, причем здесь код-гольф? Он же давно разрешен. Последние обсуждения касаются именно «вопросов-соревнований-по-анимации», а не код-гольфа.

Comment: @eanmos как это читается можно, конечно, уточнить на сайте о [русском языке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), но я вижу и использовал здесь обособление категории, а не равенство. Пример: *"кот (млекопитающее)"*. Код-гольф здесь при том, что именно с него появилась метка [tag:соревнование] и эта же метка должна быть на соответствующих вопросах-соревнованиях по анимации и любой другой теме, подходящей для ruSO.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но вопросы по анимации не являются код-гольфом, вот и все. А история происхождения метки [tag:соревнование] может быть какой угодно. Я не придираюсь и не настаиваю, просто мне было не понятно причем здесь код-гольф.

Comment: @eanmos по-моему, вы снова видите что-то такое, чего нет в моём сообщении. Основной посыл в том, что **любое** соревнование (код-гольф, не код-гольф) стоит называть здесь именно *соревнованием*, а не *конкурсом*. Не нужно делать акцент на какой-то обособленной теме, вроде анимации, или чего-то другого.

Comment: Проблома не в этом, а в закрываемых вопросах. Вот и начинается игра в кошки-мышки на поле тегов

Comment: @avp не очень понятно к чему относится ваш комментарий. В сообщении речь о терминологии, которую следует использовать дабы не вносить путаницу.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вы имеете в виду терминологию, которую должны использовать в обсуждениях участники Меты?

Comment: @avp да. Т.к. на ruSO уже есть устоявшееся понятие термина "конкурс".