# Что делать с конкурсом?

Tags: обсуждение, соревнование

Вот этот конкурс - [Новогодний арифметический конкурс 2023](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1482049/228791) - я уже вижу, что зря его затеял. 4 ответа, и 18 голосов за все ответы в сумме - это не конкурс.

Отменять - тоже не решение. Продлевать - а будут ли желающие поучаствовать?

На следующий год точно ничего делать не буду, но что делать в этом?

Comment: Наверное упор только на битовые операции повысил порог для ответа :) В следующем году можно наоборот запретить битовые операции :)

Comment: Просто год выдался особенный. Специальный такой год.

Comment: Индикатор ситуации. Ничего тут делать не надо, ознакомились и ладно

Comment: можно конкурс накинуть

Comment: дополнительно напомню, что [соревнование — это не конкурс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11166/176217).

Comment: Я его почему-то раньше не видел... Так бы поучаствовал...