# Вопрос-игра - насколько приветствуется?

Tags: обсуждение, игра, новое

Как я понимаю, целью сообщества является создание полезных реперов вида "вопрос-ответ". Поправьте, ежели не прав.

Допустим, я хочу создать игровой вопрос, непосредственно не относящийся к идее программирования, но затрагивающий другие тематики сообщества, например, систематику, биоинформатику, структурную консолидацию, графы и т.п.

Как обозначить таковой вопрос? Какие метки ставить? Нужно ли размещать призы победителям? И как это сделать сразу (у меня странный опыт по созданию более чем одного приза, может, что-то и поменялось с тех пор)?

P.S. Главное тут - игровой вопрос. Ответить можно, формально, не зная ни один язык программирования. Просто приложить голову. И какими метками это обозначить?

Comment: [tag:любой-язык] и [tag:алгоритм]? И что такое "приз"? [Конкурсный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)?

Comment: [Вопрос-соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf)? @αλεχολυτ

Comment: @aepot и ещё надо не забывать, что это [не одно и то же](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11166/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я о том же, кажется автор про это и спрашивал

Comment: Я приветствую все, что не скучно

Comment: @avp правила сайта не одобряют широту ваших приветствий

Comment: @andreymal, их давно пора уже поменять, иначе тут все скоро совсем загнется

Comment: @avp "Вся система прогнила! Всю систему надо менять!"

Comment: Не советую вообще задавать такие вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474232/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-python

Comment: Лет 10 загибается, да никак не загнется .. Скорее головная компания всё своими AI инициативами погубит.

Comment: Соревнования разрешены, вопрос как его организовать и какой критерий победы выбрать. Просто число голосов - плохой критерий, ибо те, кто опубликовал ответ позже, оказываются в невыгодном положении. У меня была мысль, что можно использовать один формат соревнований, который иногда применялся на форумах, когда роль жюри играют сами участники соревнования. Сначала идет этап приема ответов. Затем через определенное время прием ответов прекращается, и каждый участник должен выставить оценку ответам всех других участников. Победитель, соответственно, кто набрал больше всех баллов.

Comment: @nchistov почему не советуешь?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну-у мне его вроде бы закрыли, кучу против появились. В общем видно что вопрос плохой.

Answer (score -1):

Про [конкурсные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) в комментариях уже написали и @nchistov правильно [подсветил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12875/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F#comment55881_12875), что формат вопросов явно указывающий на **соревнование** не очень приветствуется. Всё же, механика *конкурсного вопроса* немного про другое. Конкурс нельзя объявить сразу же, и сделан он для того, чтобы привлечь внимание к вопросу, на который ещё не дали ответов, или есть желание получить больше ответов и разность мнений. При этом вопрос остаётся того же формата, каким был изначально.

Но, почему-то все забыли, что есть на SE есть целое отдельное сообщество:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Естественно оно не на русском, и вряд ли русская версия будет. Если есть желание делать данный формат в русском сообществе, лично я не вижу ничего плохого, но метку под это дело необходимо придумать, метки пока нет. И приживётся ли такой формат — думаю голоса покажут, не бойтесь пробовать, минусы пока никому не навредили, они лишь отражение мнения.

Comment: как это нет метки? [tag:соревнование] как раз делали чтобы покрыть сферу codegolf.se на русском.

Comment: Не углядел, да.