# Бесполезное знание

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

> SO — для решения практических проблем и наполнение практическими приемами, а не экскурсы в историю....Как бесполезная информация помогла/поможет набрать вам практический опыт и применить это на практике — без понятия

начало тут: [Описание какой ошибки было под номером 5 в $_FILES['pic']['error']?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604130/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-5-%d0%b2-filespicerror)

Если СО *для решения практических проблем и наполнение практическими приемами,*, то какой практический опыт(?), какое применение?, какой смысл в вопросе, который летом2016 был конкурсным и речь в нем шла (точно не помню!): *как сделать что-то не используя ни одной переменной?*

---

Меня заинтересовало куда делась ошибка №5. Уверен, что не многие знают о ней.

ха!, ну конечно. Зачем знать, если это знание бесполезно(?)

**upd** Я нашел тот вопрос: [Поменять две переменные местами не используя третью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540286/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e) .

Какое практическое применение того что можно поменять две переменные, не используя третью? Где такое можно на**к**одить? Все равно неявно используется "нечто" в качестве третьей переменной.

Если кто-то знает, то молодец, пусть купит себе медаль. Та понимаю я, что если люди знают как поменять 2 перем. не используя третью - то они супер продвинутые специалисты.

Я себе тоже могу купить медаль за то что теперь знаю что случилось с ошибкой № 5 при аплоаде файлов.

В общем, нужно мне без эмоционально все это воспринимать. А то вместо того чтобы нечто полезное делать я... занимаюсь не тем(!).

Comment: Вы из-за единственного минуса Вашему вопросу решили создать тему на Мете или по какой-то иной причине решили вынести на обсуждение личное мнение одного участника?

Comment: при чем тут минусы? Я не один раз писал что рейтинг для меня ничего не значит.  И минусов там было больше. Может я как-то бурно реагирую на всё и всех?

Comment: На вопросе по ссылке (один минус и два плюса). О чём и где Вы писали ранее, я, честно говоря, не в курсе. А реагируете скорее не бурно, а сумбурно. Попробуйте чётче формулировать Ваши мысли.

Comment: "О чём и где Вы писали ранее, я, честно говоря, не в курсе. " - раньше (летом2016) я ГДЕ-ТО писал о том,  что рейтинг на СО мне не важен => это я о том что именно это мнение\вопрос (Бесполезное знание) я создал не и-за и минусов и не из-за какого-то мифического, виртуального  рейтинга.

Comment: Мнение участника "Алексей Шиманский" может не совпадать со мнением сообщества. А может и совпадать) Лично я к вопросам бесполезным с практической точки зрения отношусь нормально, официальные правила тоже их не запрещают

Comment: "Мнение участника "Алексей Шиманский" может не совпадать со мнением сообщества." - ааа, он оно как Михалыч %:)). Думаю что мне надо меньше реагировать на мнения с которыми я не согласен. Но  так никто и не ответил "Какая практическая польза от конкурсного вопроса, который был летом 2016. - "как с помощью одной переменной сделать что-то..."" .  Не помню точное  :(( содержание того вопроса.

Comment: Прочитал вопрос раз пять, понял что вы недовольны, но о чём спрашиваете, не понял. Для чего нужен вопрос, ссылки на который нет, и для чего нужен ваш. Задумайтесь, если бы ваш вопрос мешал сообществу, его бы закрыли и грохнули.

Comment: @D-side так его вроде и закрывали. только видимо этот трэшак кто-то решил переоткрыть. Собсн, как обычно тут и происходит. То откроют то закроют)

Comment: **D-side**, третий раз! повторяю: какой практический опыт(?), какое применение?, какой смысл в вопросе, который летом2016 был конкурсным и речь в нем шла (точно не помню!): как сделать что-то не используя ни одной переменной? - ссылку на этот вопрос я не помню. и точное название не помню. Да уже и не важно(?).

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: `(a,b)=(b,a)` - как-то так!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если вы не обратили внимание: у того вопроса стоит метка [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Это значит, что вопрос относится к тематике [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), которую сообщество [признало допустимой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84).

Это значит, что вопрос интересен не самой представленной технической проблемой, а способами решения. Это могут быть нестандартные подходы, малоизвестные языки программирования, разнообразные трюки, которые позволяют выполнить условия соревнования. Условия, как правило, объявляет автор соревнования (например, побеждает решение с минимальным объемом кода).

Такие вопросы одновременно выполняют соревновательно-развлекательную роль и позволяют участникам обменяться нестандартным опытом.

Конкретно обмен двух переменных значениями без дополнительной памяти - классическая задачка на сообразительность.

Comment: теперь ясно-понятно.

Comment: Анектод: Приходит программэр на собеседование (ИЛИ  студент на экзамен(!)). Его спрашивают: "Что с ошибкой №5 ... ?"  :%)

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy и про T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM тоже спросят!

Answer (score 6):

Знание не бывает бесполезным.

А если что-то неинтересно, всегда можно просто пройти мимо.