# Требования к соревнованиям (в т. ч. гольфу)

Tags: обсуждение, правила

Коллеги, в последнее время у нас выросло количество участников, недовольных слишком неформальным определением того, что же есть вопрос-[соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Давайте попробуем формализовать критерии того, чего мы ожидаем от таки вопросов.

Прошу предлагать правила, желательно одно на ответ. Прошу также голосовать за правила, которые вы считаете хорошими, против правил, которые вы считаете плохими, и оставлять комментарии по этому поводу.

---

Вот ссылка [на начало обсуждения](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37722150#37722150) этого вопроса в чате. (Ахтунг, флейм инсайд!)

Comment: А мы рассматриваем все возможные соревнования или только гольф, где выигрыш - минимальный размер?

Comment: Я так понимаю, любые соревнования.

Comment: Любые, конечно!

Comment: Отразил сие в заголовке.

Comment: Нужна фотография инициатора гольфа в гольфах.

Comment: @Aid: А если автор устраивает соревнование без гольфа, то тогда без гольфов?

Comment: @VladD, тогда в килте.

Comment: Я считаю, что это вообще не относится к тематике сообщества и для игр есть https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Alex78191: Это не тема данного опроса.

Comment: Можете отсюда взять правила https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Alex78191 этот вопрос обсуждался [ранее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/178779)

Comment: Коллеги, было бы здорово суммировать правила в одном понятном FAQ–вопросе, который я бы в последствие смог добавить в справку.

Answer (score 10):

1. Требовать от организатора соревнования добавления в вопрос сниппета с результатами соревнования.
2. Шаблоны сниппетов для разных типов соревнований держать в ответах в отдельном посте на Мете.
3. В описании метки [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) держать помимо общих правил (которые мы сейчас выбираем) ссылку на вопрос с шаблонами.

Comment: по идее это должно было быть тремя ответами :-)

Comment: Тогда уж и нужно требовать от автора и определения формата строки-заголовка для сниппетов. (Примеры можно в тот же мета-пост.)

Comment: это атомарное требование

Comment: @Nofate, все или ничего? :-)

Comment: Второе вытекает из первого, а третье из второго. Голосовать за них по-отдельности странно.

Comment: @Nofate, а всегда ли можно ранжировать результаты?

Comment: @Grundy а как иначе *объективно* выбрать победителя?

Comment: А никак, на усмотрение автора вопроса например :-)

Comment: @Grundy тогда это уже не *спортивное* мероприятие, а конкурс "развлеки автора вопроса"ю

Comment: @Nofate, ну конкурсы ж разные бывают? не только на кратчайшее решение

Comment: @Nofate: А кстати. И правда, есть же popularity contest — выигрыш по голосам.

Comment: @VladD. _popularity contest_ мне кажется не взлетит, потому что у всех будет одинаковое значение :-D

Comment: @Grundy: У нас взлетал же. В любом случае, автор должен предоставить сортировку, которая гарантировано выявит победителя. Просто к-во голосов имеет право быть первым ключом.

Comment: @VladD для выигрыша по голосам - считаем в табличке голоса. Никаких проблем.

Comment: @Nofate: Хорошо, это значит, что сниппеты должны быть более-менее настраиваемыми.

Comment: @VladD, я подразумевал, что будет по шаблону на каждый тип соревнования (на каждый способ подсчета очков)

Comment: @Nofate: Нереалистично. Вот в моём последнем вопросе сортировка по (1) распарсился ли заголовок? (2) соответствует ли вопрос правилам? (3) вскрыт ли вопрос взломщиком? (4) количество токенов. Пункт 3 уникальный.

Comment: @VladD, но у вас довольно нетипичное соревнование (что, конечно, только плюс). Большинство будет сводиться к 2-3 категориям, скорее всего.

Comment: @Nofate: Это да. То есть скрипты всё равно (иногда) нужно будет допиливать.

Answer (score 5):

Обязательное обсуждение в специальном [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----), либо в вопросе-песочнице на мете

Comment: Обсуждение штука номинальная, вбросил ссылку и вроде как есть. Как будем определять, что сообщество дало зелёный свет?

Comment: @D-side, большинством голосов в чате например :-)

Comment: Разверните мысль. В чат может зайти кто угодно. Большинства участников всея ru.SO мы там не дождёмся. Что тогда?

Comment: Поясните, что делать с вопросами, на которые повесили метку 'соревнование', чтобы спасти вопрос от закрытия. Чисто технологический момент, но всё же.

Comment: @AK, собственно ничего, метка вешается _после_ обсуждения, а не до. Поэтому нельзя просто взять и навесить ее на любой вопрос.

Comment: @D-side, собственно большинство участников и соревнование пропустит как таковое.

Comment: @Grundy тогда о каком большинстве в чате речь?

Comment: @AK, ничего, взяли и повеили :)

Answer (score 5):

Если задача заключается в составлении программы, реализующей конкретный алгоритм, в описании *должен* присутствовать контрольный пример. Т.е. ожидаемый результат выполнения при заданных входных значениях.

Comment: Вопрос в том, должен ли пример являться _нормативным_. То есть, если что-либо правильно работает на данном примере, должно ли это приводить к автоматическому зачёту данного ответа?

Comment: @VladD Как показывает практика, ТС может не учесть некоторых нюансов, которые всплывают по ходу дела. И контрольный пример может все таки быть не достаточным для проверки всех ситуаций. Да и соблюдение одного примера может выражаться в `print "результат"` и засчитывать это за ответ явно не следует :)

Comment: Интересный вопрос, возможно ли добавление уточняющих задачу тестовых примеров. И что делать, если уже дан ответ, который под новый пример не подходит.

Comment: @VladD Думаю по ситуации, в последнем вопросе с сортировкой же договорились и решили уточнить про букву ё уже при данных ответах. вроде особо никто не обиделся. Понятно, что надо стремится что бы вопрос изначально давал исчерпывающую информацию по особым случаям. Но никто не застрахован от ошибок

Comment: Ну, мне кажется, что уточнять условие, инвалидируя при этом уже данный ответ, не очень хорошо. Поэтому такая смена вопроса стоит того, внестиеё в вопрос и выделить жирным, ну и извиниться перед теми, кто уже дал ответ.

Comment: @VladD Что то вы не договорили фразу :) Я согласен, что добавление любых доп условий на ходу, это криво. Конечно вопрос должен быть максимально проработан до того, как задан. Но оговаривать в правилах, что текст вопроса не может быть изменен после первого ответа, не готов. Бывают форсмажоры, особенно если задающий вопрос еще не очень опытен

Answer (score 4):

В случае гольфа принимать только ответы, содержащие не только ужатый код, но и развернутый (желательно с комментариями).

Answer (score 2):

Необязательное, один из возможных критериев победителя (по желанию автора)

Чтобы и читать, и писать код было комфортно предлагается считать *токены*, а не байты. Код лучше читать с комфортом, если это не конкурс начинающих обфускаторов.

Токен - атомарная синтаксическая конструкция языка. Например, объявление `int check(const char *str)` состоит из 6 токенов. название функции - 1, название типа - 2, название параметра - 1, 2 скобки.
Основная проблема в том, как считать токены, как определить, у какого токена длина 1, а какого длина `n` символов. Предлагается все, что можно сократить (ухудшив читабельность) считать единичным токеном, а все, что сократить невозможно - токеном полным (n символов).

Например:

- Значение переменной - токен длиной n, с учетом кавычек, если они есть
- ключевое слово - n (никак не заменить),
- незначимые пробелы (например, логическое разделение блоков кода) не
  учитывать,
- значимые - учитывать как токен длиной 1,
- тип данных - токен 1 (всегда typedef написать можно), за исключением
  auto.
- Операторы (любые, мносимвольные тоже) - токен n, точка с запятой в
  окончании строки (и другие подобные символы) также считается
  оператором длиной 1
- импорты-инклюды-дефайны - токен n (не заменить),
- модификаторы вызова а ля __stdcall - токен 1
- комментарии - не учитывать

Comment: `return` - это 6, а `__stdcall` - 1 - за что бы? Не, что-то мне вообще не нравится такой подход - какие-то нечестные токены и какое-то не такое отношение к гольфу...

Comment: @Qwertiy, `__stdcall` можно сократить с помощью `define`, `return` нельзя

Comment: Да ну? http://ideone.com/3ITWCd

Comment: выглядит слишком сложно

Comment: Я бы не устанавливал это _обязательным_ правилом. Но имеет смысл положить _шаблон_ этого/такого правила (тщательно сформулированный!) в отдельную тему на Мете, в которой мы соберём и будем поддерживать правила в рабочем состоянии, чтобы автор гольф-вопроса мог при желании сослаться на него.

Comment: Проблема сложности чтения "обфусцированного" кода только потому, что многие постят только такой вариант. я например всегда стараюсь написать короткий, конкурсный, код и его как минимум нормально отформатированную, по действию на строку, а иногда и немного модифицированную версию с комментариями по каждой строке. А именно требование сжатия кода побайтно сподвигает на решение той же задачи более короткими токенами из за чего иногда в корне меняет подход к решению. И таким образом позволяет показать больше интересных (для специалиста) трюков. Хотя "по желанию автора вопроса" - согласен

Comment: @m9_psy define тоже должно быть в коде

Answer (score 2):

В прежних подобных мероприятиях замечал разбор кода Участником. Было бы интересно проследить за ходом мысли автора ответа, построчно, особенно новичкам и/или искренне удивляющимся некоторым конструкциям, к коим я отношу свою скромную персону.

Comment: Ну то есть как бы да. Это было бы неплохо. Но делать это _обязательным_?

Comment: @VladD: я хоть и собрал кое-какое, но решение на Java и PHP, но то, что я ума не приложу как это решение работает на другом языке меня удивляет сильно. Просто очень интересно. Как?

Comment: @TimurVI Некоторые особенности языков очень тяжело осмыслить не зная основ этого языка. человеку привыкшему к обычному пошаговому алгоритму, записываемому строго слева на право, тяжело перестроится на чтение всяких лямбд, map и т.п. Единственный выход думаю - попросить конкретного автора кода привести его разбор (возможно показав ссылку на какой нибудь хороший разбор, что бы он понимал что от него хотят). К сожалению заставлять всех тратить время на это не представляется возможным. иногда разбор занимает больше, чем написание кода :)

Answer (score 2):

В обязательном порядке размещать в вопросе ссылку на обсуждение (а то в последнем гольфе в комментах отсылки на обсуждение есть, а где оно - хрен найдешь)

Answer (score -5):

Опять таки, в связи с последним гольфом, следует определиться, какие символы допустимо использовать в коде. ИМХО, в общем случае, самым лучшим вариантом будет разрешение только ASCII в диапазоне 0x20-0x7E (т.е. без управляющих) и, возможно, расширенный 0x80-0xFF, но не уверен.

Для задач, где гипотетически может быть востребовано, разрешать Unicode, но не графем напрямую, а в виде code point'ов

Поясню.

Например вот такой ответ совершенно неудобоварим:

```
<?php
function p($s) {
for($l=-1;$l++<6;){foreach(str_split($s)as$y)printf('%8s',strtr(decbin(ord("8||��|�||D0���������P������||���|~���� �D���� ��8|�||| ||"{$l*10+$y})),'01',' #'));echo"\n";}
}
p('0123456789876543210');
```

Собственно единственное применение подобных строк - хранение данных в наиболее сжатом виде. Их запрет абсолютно одинаково скажется на всех участниках(в том смысле, что никто преимущества не потеряет (хотя гольф вообще не страдает толерантностью к длине языковых конструкций)) и в разы поднимет читабельность кода и сделает возможным его скопировать и воспроизвести без шаманских плясок.

Comment: Мне показалось на секундочку, что тут меня упомянули :)

Answer (score -12):

Запрет на использование всякого *барахла* (долго думал над формулировкой), типа [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/). Не знаю, как формально выразить запрет на нечитабельные экзотические языки - возможно, разрешить только определенные языки и определенные их реализции. Предложу такой список: C, C++, C#, Python, Ruby, Java, JavaScript, Perl (тут еще можно поспорить насчет читабельности), Bash, SQL, PHP, R, D, Assembly x86, Go.

Comment: Хм. Что-то не пошло это предложение. Вместо этого, возможно, имеет смысл в конкурсах подсчитывать не баллы, а _токены_, как в предпоследнем соревновании? То есть не наказывать за длинные идентификаторы, форматирование пробелами и незначащие комментарии.

Comment: Но это, наверное, снова-таки на усмотрение автора вопроса.

Comment: [*"Нытьё"* на ту же тему на PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6983/48189).

Comment: @VladD, токены - отлично, надо только договориться, что считать токеном с длинной 1, а что с длинной n. Например, значение переменной - токен длиной n, ключевое слово - n (никак не заменить), незначимые пробелы (например, логическое разделение блоков кода) не учитывать, значимые - учитывать как токен длиной 1, объявление типа - токен 1 (всегда typedef написать можно, если выгодно - в результате уродство). Операторы (любые, мносимвольные тоже) - токен 1, импорты-инклюды - токен n (не заменить), модификаторы вызова а ля __stdcall - токен 1

Comment: @m9_psy, возможно стоит из этого комментария сделать отдельный ответ

Comment: @Grundy: Это тянет на отдельное обсуждение темы — как правильнее всего подсчитывать токены. Там есть несколько подводных камней. Например, рефлексия.

Comment: Проблема не особо остра, я как то не видел что бы у нас часто использовали экзотику (в отличие от английского golf), по приколу вот я сделал один ответ на Pyth. Автор вопроса может явно это оговорить. Хотя конечно напрягает, когда сидишь, потеешь, рассматриваешь подходы ... а тут приходит кто то и пишет, что эта задача в языке "XX" решается одним символом :) А завтра я приду и на сверхсложную задачу скажу, что вот же, вчера сделал язык который делает только это и опять же одним символом