# Вопросы конкурсы, нужны/не нужны, можно/нельзя

Tags: обсуждение, соревнование

Сотоварищи, дамы и господа, мадам/месье, друзья,

В последнее время на сайте участились т.н. вопросы конкурсы, примеры:

1. [Новогодний конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061127/%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-2020-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)
2. [Поиск слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951991/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81)
3. [Как анимировать слово StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105132/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-stackoverflow)
4. [Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113095/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f)
5. и т.д.

Мнение сообщества как всегда полярно разделилось, привожу мнения:

> Вы долбанулись? Этот псевдоконкурс «по своему индивидуальному сценарию» не соответствует правилам сайта по причине слишком общей формулировки, его надлежит незамедлительно отменить и закрыть.

Противоположное мнение:

> А разве он должен нравится или нет? Это просто работа. Пусть и легкая, несложная, но работа. Для кого-то она может быть полезна.

Как распределяются голоса можно легко увидеть посмотрев на сами вопросы.

**Внимание вопрос:** какое примем решение?

1. Закрываем такие вопросы, авторов в пытошные подвалы
2. Пусть такие вопросы будут - всем будет весело.

P.S. Свое мнение намеренно не привожу, не хочу шунтировать мнение народа своим ромбиком и тяжелой репутацией.

**Update**

1. Вопрос и ответы сделаны *общими*, то есть репутация ТС и ответчиков не меняется (имхо это повышает объективность дискуссии)
2. К вопросу @UModeL - возможно с вашей колокольни незаметна актуальность темы, не берусь говорить за статистику, но примерно 10-20% тревог поднимаемых юзерами как раз относится к вопросам такого рода, лишним свидетельством в пользу этого является также вся дискуссия вокруг этого вопроса. Если считаете, что тема не актуальна, можете не участвовать - это ваше право.

Comment: Такие "конкурсы", конечно, офтопик, но раз в год - можно :-)

Comment: Если это «для веселья», то повеселились, а потом убрали за собой — и все довольны...

Comment: А ещё, мне кажется, если регламентировать проводить такое веселье под знаком «Общих» вопросов и ответов, количество желающих повеселиться поубавится. Считаю это всё ничем иным, как взаимной накруткой репутации.

Comment: @vp_arth можно не убирать, а лочить (чтобы не всплывали) - хороший вариант

Comment: Допустимы. Оставить. Не банить. Полезны. ;)

Comment: «2. Поиск слов» — ну не знаю, тут я вообще никакого конкурса не вижу, просто вопрос с конкретной задачей.

Comment: @vp_arth: уважаемый, поясните мне, что даёт репутация конкретно на этой площадке? Пусть даже 1М. Я действительно не понимаю, без сарказма. Бесполезные привилегии и циферки рядом с кружочками?

Comment: @UModeL, Понятия не имею, но тем не менее. Люди любят циферки.

Comment: Да вот, хотя бы опустите взгляд чуть ниже: «я все-таки занимаю 10-е место по кол-во полезных тревог».. И это даже не про репутацию)

Comment: «Свое мнение намеренно не привожу, не хочу шунтировать мнение народа», — это, конечно, демократично, но народу не хватает сильной руки модератора. Кто хотел, уже высказал своё мнение за пол года. Теперь нужно решение, и его должен принять человек с ромбом.

Comment: @nomnoms12 если уж на то пошло, то модератор на SO - это исполнительная власть, а не законодательная. Так что не надо тут про сильные руки )

Comment: @Barmaley: "В последнее время на сайте участились..." И какова частота, уважаемый? "... и т.д." - это не ответ. Чем вызвано поднятие этой темы сейчас? Прошу подробнее изложить причину в вопросе.

Comment: Голосую за переоткрытие, имхо это обсуждение получается более качественным из-за нейтральной позиции ТСа и лучше старый вопрос прибить как дубликат этого

Comment: @yolosora да не важно. Модераторы, видимо, с голосами не считаются)

Comment: Неправда, сижу и смотрю на голоса. Старое обсуждение на которое ссылались как на копию - оно слишком частное и оттененное личными пристрастиями ТС... Сделал вопрос общим, чтобы избежать обвинений в накрутке репы :)

Comment: «репутация ТС и ответчиков не меняется» — так ведь мета вроде в принципе никак не меняет репутацию?

Comment: @Barmaley На мой взгляд, Вы немного не так поняли комментарии `@UmodeL`. Причиной этого возможно была сверх эмоциональная подача комментариев с его стороны.  Ему, как раз очень не наплевать на тему обсуждения  конкурсов.  Он сам активно участвует в конкурсах. Посмотрите [эту его работу.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924052/28748) Его работы, на мой взгляд очень высокого уровня. Просто иногда так складывается ситуация, что человек не выдерживает, когда идет полоса постоянного непонимания. Он активно отвечает на вопросы, а они в последнее время очень низкого качества.

Comment: @Barmaley Картинки, невразумительный текст. Тем не менее он пытается достучаться до вопрошающего. Чего же он хочет. Делает вновь и вновь варианты ответов, я вижу, что он при этом выкладывается полностью, и когда в конце концов получает ответ от вопрошающего, что это мне не подходит, то поневоле начинают накапливаться негативные эмоции. Я это чувствую, потому что просматриваю все вопросы-ответы сильных отвечающих. в темах SVG, CSS, JS  Да, на мету нужно идти с холодной головой и быть готовым ко всему.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116557/discussion-on-question-by-barmaley-------).

Comment: @Barmaley И ещё видна одна причина эмоционального всплеска - вот эта именно травля конкурсов со стороны одного человека в течение года, который спать спокойно не может, не послав тревогу на закрытие конкурса.

Comment: Вопрос вопросу рознь, так что я бы исходил из самого вопроса, насколько он интересен...

Answer (score -14, accepted):

В итоге всех обсуждений предлагается следующее решение:

Вопросы-конкурсы разрешены при соблюдении 2-х условий:

1. Если автор вопроса обьявляет вопрос конкурсным с вознаграждением, скажем **не менее 100 баллов репутации**
2. Если автор не объявляет вознаграждение, то модератор самовольно объявляет вопрос **"общим"**

При таком подходе мы сохраним веселье и избавимся от обвинений авторов таких вопросов в накрутках репутации.

Ответ на вопрос об идентификации вопроса-конкурса, предлагаю решать модераторам, но строго по тревогам выставляемым юзерами, тревога типа: *считаю данный вопрос конкурсом, просьба принять меры*. Модератор рассматривает тревогу, если тревога обоснована предлагает автору назначить награду за ответы или сразу делает его общим.

**Update**

1. Очевидно, что стоимость вознаграждения по крайней мере должна быть не ниже стоимости репы набранной публикацией до момента объявления вознаграждения (вознаграждение можно назначить только через 2 дня с момента публикации)
2. Вопросы указанные ТС как примеры вопросов-конкурсов уже помечены как общие.

Comment: Вознаграждение можно назначить не ранее, чем через 2 дня с момента публикации вопроса. Всё это время ТС может собирать репу, а если потом сделать сообщение общим, то ранее полученная репа всё равно останется у ТС насколько я помню. И ещё неясно сколько модератор обязуется выждать с момента появления возможности объявить конкурс до момента установки галочки "общий", если ТС отказывается назначать конкурс. Кстати, конкурс может назначить и не только ТС. Как эта ситуация будет рассматриваться в таком аспекте? Плюс если сделать вопрос общим, то и ответы других (невиновных) участников обесценятся.

Comment: Идеальных решений не будет, это надо понимать. Вознаграждение должно быть не менее суммы набранной репы.

Comment: Понятно, что идеальных не будет, но если принимается/предлагается какое-то решение, то возникшие неясные моменты стоит так или иначе прояснить как можно раньше, чтобы избежать разнотолков, недопониманий и новых вопросов "Почему не закрыли оффтоп", "Это не конкурс, а чепуха", "Модератор-самодур" и т.д, и т.п.

Comment: Я уже давно понял, что модератор при любом раскладе будет крайним :)

Comment: Всегда можно просто так взять и сложить с себя полномочия :) Но здесь дело не столько в модераторстве, сколько в фиксировании правил по этим "конкурсным" вопросам.

Comment: А что такое ТС?

Comment: ТС == Topic Starter

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, почему мои вопросы сделаны общими? Причем вот так сразу, единолично. Во-первых, это было только предложение, с которым не все могут быть согласны. Во-вторых, вознаграждение по первому вопросу было назначено 500, дважды. По второму вопросу вознаграждение было назначено 200, однако вопрос тогда мой удалили. Я не согласен с таким решением, и считаю его естественно несправедливым.

Comment: Согласен с вами, вернее с тем, что вы лично не согласны. Я внимательно прочитал все дискуссии и сформулировал мнение сообщества в своем ответе. Решение принято - можете жаловаться - это ваше право.

Comment: Бред какой-то. При чём тут накрутки вообще? **Псевдоконкурсы вредят качеству базы знаний** и это не имеет никакого отношения к репутациям участников. Да и вообще я не понимаю, где тут накрутку увидели...

Comment: По моему, слишком сложно. В предыдущем обсуждении больше всего голосов набрало предложение проводить неформатные конкурсы на мете, это лучше бы решило и проблему фарма репутации, и проблему засорения базы знаний.

Comment: "В итоге всех обсуждений предлагается следующее решение". Кто так решил?

Comment: Соглашусь с @MSDN.WhiteKnight, имхо решение слишком перегруженное, проще в таком случае проводить соревнования на мете или проводить на основном сайте с последующим переносом на мету

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, в предыдущем обсуждении это где?

Comment: @Sevastopol' https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10374/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, вы читали только "Конкурс на Мете"? А под итог "Что можно сделать?"  читали?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight просто будет тогда засорение базы знаний на Мете

Answer (score 20):

Моё мнение по этому вопросу такое:

В текущем виде эти вопросы нарушают правила сайта.

И надо эту деятельность

а) узаконить, потому что идея хорошая, полезная и увеличивает количество добра во вселенной и на stackoverflow.

б) утвердить какие-то формальные правила, потому что в текущем виде оно идёт вразрез с текущим набором правил ru so.

У нас же есть отдельная ниша для проведения соревнований ака code golf'ов  - и в ней допускается некоторое отклонение от правил.

Я несколько раз эту тему обсуждал с разными лицами, поэтому сейчас намеренно не ухожу в конкретику, какие правила должны быть -- я просто хочу рамочно обозначить мнение:

> в текущем виде против правил сайта, но вещь хорошая, поэтому я за
> легализацию

Comment: Мое мнение очень близко к этому :) Было бы справедливо легализовать конкурсы для людей занимающихся версткой/дизайном/etc., но нужно придумать разумные ограничения, что не так тривиально. Если просто разрешить - в теории может появится пользователь который каждый день будет флудить десятками вопросов вида "анимируйте буквы, трусы, самолет, бубенцы" и с этим уже ничего не сделаешь. После прошлого нового года как раз такие вещи участились и назрел по этому поводу холивар.

Comment: «и в ней допускается некоторое отклонение от правил» — хм, например?

Comment: кстати о [соревнованиях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5292/186999)

Comment: @Grundy отличный пост откопан. Жесткие правила и (что даже более важно, их соблюдение) для противоречивого типа вопросов – это хорошая идея.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, по началу их даже придерживались, но потом что-то пошло не так :)

Comment: @Grundy не вижу никаких препятствий возродить практику.

Answer (score 9):

Коллеги, перестаньте заниматься самообманом с базой знаний и отстаньте от вопросов и ответов, которые вам не нравятся, как замусоривающие эту самую, несуществующую базу.

Для создания настоящей базы знаний по программированию тут попросту не предусмотрены инструменты, позволяющие нужным образом структурировать накопленный объем вопросов и ответов на них.

Поэтому не стоит в очередной раз провоцировать уход с сайта людей, которые с удовольствием делятся своими наработками с другими. При этом абсолютно не важно, соответствуют ли эти темы формальным правилам.

Важно же, чтобы эти темы были в рамках IT и желательно, чтобы они были интересны хотя бы небольшой группе участников.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116597/discussion-on-answer-by-avp-------).

Answer (score 9):

#### Все придумано до нас =)

Это вопрос уже обсуждался (один в один, на мой взгляд) в рамках [Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/6) В обоих темах рассматриваются одни и те же вопросы, с одного и того же ракурса. В прошлый раз мы вместе нашли общий знаменатель, который стоит брать в расчет, если мы хотим поднять вопрос еще раз. Вот еще несколько хороших вопросов про соревнования на Stack Overflow на русском:

- [Узаконим гольф?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/6)
- [Требования к соревнованиям (в т. ч. гольфу)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5292/6)

И еще несколько сопутствующих обсуждений:

- [Ещё раз про [соревнования] и [code-golf]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10319/6)
- [Новогодний конкурс узаконен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9961/6)

#### Хорошие правила — ключ к разгадке

Как мне кажется, запустить сообщества на русском языке по другим темам в рамках Stack Exchange будет довольно сложно. Как результат, любые инициативы, которые заканчивались новыми сообществами на английском языке, скорее всего, будут заканчиваться расширением тематики Stack Overflow на русском. Вопросы соревнования тому пример. На самом деле, это не плохо, это просто другой подход к [изначально взятому курсу по разделению подсообществ запуском новых сайтов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/).

Самое потрясающее в том, что уже сейчас в рамках Stack Exchange (то есть модели вопросов и ответов) уже успешно уживаются самые разнообразные сообщества, начиная от [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) и заканчивая [Буддизмом](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/). Например, не так давно я столкнулся с Law Stack Exchange. [Как оказалось](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1002/34045), в силу специфики законов и права, задавать конкретные прикладные вопросы на сайте нельзя, так как это может грозить отвечающему судебными последствиями. Поэтому участники требуют, чтобы вопросы задавались [в особом виде](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302/34045).

Когда происходит конфликт интересов, который мы видим сейчас с вопросами соревнованиями, мы можем попробовать задать себе вопрос — «Есть ли те, кому это действительно надо? Если да, каким образом сделать так, чтобы те, кто хочет развивать знания на выбранную тему и те, кому эта тема не нравится жили бок о бок, наслаждаясь обществом друг друга?» Абсолютно точно участники есть. Остается лишь создать рабочие правила, которые устраивают всех (как минимум, в рамках рабочего компромисса).

Comment: Насколько я вижу, в сети Stack Exchange нет ни одного сообщества, на которых подобные псевдоконкурсы были бы онтопиком. В частности, они не соответствуют ни правилам webmasters, ни правилам codegolf

Comment: Ну и, собственно, за прошедшие полгода никто так и не потрудился создать рабочие правила

Comment: @andreymal Отличное замечание по поводу правил. Поддерживаю. Думаю, самое время этим заняться!

Comment: давайте этим займемся. ибо ситуация точно вышла из под контроля.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, буквально несколько интересных вопросов из всей огромной массы, которые набрали много голосов, вызвали интерес сообщества и получили активность (что кстати говоря прямо выгодно ruSO) - это выход ситуации из под контроля? Не думаю. Очевидно же, что только несколько человек поднимают время от времени шумиху и устраивают холевар в сообществе. Такая "борьба за справедливость" больше смахивает на провокацию, которая вносит только раскол в сообщество, а это для сообщества вредно. Но почему-то за подобные действия у нас наказание не предусмотрено.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ситуация вышла из-под контроля - я имею ввиду не конкурсы как таковые, а все, что происходит по их обсуждению за последние два-три дня. Решается это, на мой взгляд, только организацией и соблюдением правил, которые стараются не ущемлять интересов участников, но сохраняют институты репутации и "вопрос-ответности". В данный момент с каждым из этих пунктов, на мой взгляд, проблема.

Answer (score 6):

Как правильно заметил @A K, в текущем виде вопросы нарушают правила и должны быть закрыты. И, к сожалению, вопросы подобного типа не тянут даже на соревнование, ибо в них нет четких критериев победы:

> Приветствуются исключительно все средства и технологии для рисования и
> создания эффекта анимации и трансформации без ограничений, а также все
> способы реализации для достижения этой цели и по своему
> индивидуальному сценарию…

Поэтому, **таким вопросам в их текущем виде не место на SO**, но…

---

Вот слова @Sevastopol' (*цитата — [отсюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11093/18534)*):

> *Всё что я здесь делаю и выкладываю на ruSO, включая все ответы, я это
> делаю не для себя. И в свободное от работы время. Я умею всё это, и
> практика/опыт/знания у меня многолетние (как и у многих здесь
> участников), и проектов готовых за много лет уже сотни. И понты
> различные мне ни к чему, всё это мы уже проходили. Это всё для
> новичков, поэтому и прошу уважения к себе и к своей работе. Благодарю.*

Думаю, никто не будет спорить, что многолетний опыт работы — бесценен. И из ответов на такие вопросы действительно можно многому научиться. И мне лично не хочется, чтобы весь этот опыт канул в никуда (если такие вопросы будут просто закрываться или удаляться). Кроме того, мне не нравится, что сейчас весь этот опыт валяется в «свалке из бессвязных примеров анимации».

В качестве решения предлагаю такой вариант: нужно разбить все вопросы про анимацию на *отдельные*, *конкретные* составные вопросы и написать для них *отдельные*, *конкретные* ответы<sup>†</sup>. Каждый такой вопрос/ответ будут решать *отдельную*, *конкретную* проблему. *Отдельную* и *конкретную*.

У такого способа поделится опытом, который был предложен Джоэлом Спольски и Джеффом Этвудом еще в 2008 году<sup>*</sup>, куча преимуществ:

1. Решение *конкретной* проблемы, которая возникла у человека, можно будет легко найти через поисковик, ведь у *отдельного*, *конкретного* вопроса будет хорошо индексируемый заголовок;
2. Вопросы перестанут закрывать, потому что на них можно будет дать объективный ответ;
3. Если у меня будет *отдельная*, *конкретная* проблема, то мне не придется фильтровать огромное количество ненужной (для решения моей проблемы) информации, которая на данный момент присутствует в таких вопросах;
4. Прекратятся бесконечные холивары;
5. @andreymal, наконец, сможет спать спокойно.

---

<sup>† Например, в случае вопроса про анимацию знака рубля, его можно разбить на вопрос по работе `keyframes`, свойству `animation`, `transform` и т. д. Разбиение, конечно, утрировано.</sup>

<sup>‡ Слова «отдельный» и «конкретный» проходят рефреном. Надеюсь, не переборщил.</sup>

<sup>* Да, мы сейчас переизобрели StackOverflow.</sup>

Comment: «не хочется, чтобы весь этот опыт канул в никуда» — мне тоже не хочется, но Sevastopol' почему-то именно выкидыванием опыта и занимается.

Comment: «нужно разбить все вопросы про анимацию на отдельные, конкретные составные вопросы» — а я про это ещё полгода назад говорил, да.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, о чем вы? Это вообще не цитата.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, но здесь нет ссылки на авторитет. Может, я как-то не удачно выразил мысль? Я имел в виду, что тот способ делиться знаниями, который я предлагаю, — через решения конкретных проблем — был предложен в 2008 году и положен в основу SO его основателями. Сказано это было с намеком на то, что это предложение — делится знаниями в виде решения конкретных проблем — суть предложение соблюдать правила SO, которые лежат в его основе. Намек (без какой-либо негативной коннотации) — для авторов подобных вопросов.

Comment: @eanmos ну да, немного неудачно получилось В заблуждение вводят упоминания авторов и тут же двоеточие и перечисление пунктов. Как то по другому надо акценты расставить, чтобы  не получалось разночтения, а было чётко видно, что это именно  вы говорите, а не цитируете. Впрочем это такие мелочи, что можете ничего не исправлять, всё это на ваш вкус  Я удалю свои предыдущие комментарии.

Answer (score 6):

### Предлагаю вариант возможного решения оформления анимационных конкурсов

Вопрос трудный, так как конкурсы анимации, отличаются от обычных конкурсов.

Хочу рассмотреть в деталях [**один конкурс**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748), который был проведен до выхода этого топика и на примерах проанализировать все нюансы, как стартует конкурс, как проводится, как финиширует с выбором победителя.

*Более подробно, весь текст оформления вопроса можно посмотреть, перейдя по ссылке*

---

[**Как создать анимированную иконку Stackoverflow**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748)

> Сценарий анимации:
>
> 1. Рисование контура корзины
> 2. Заполнение цветом контура
> 3. Последовательное появление 5-ти цветных полосок
> 4. Исчезновение полосок в обратном порядке.
> 5. Зацикливание появления, исчезновения цветных полосок.
>
> Как реализовать данный сценарий анимации иконки, используя одну из
> технологий, указанную в метках вопроса?

---

**Вопрос** Нарушает ли этот вопрос правила проведения конкурса?

- Заголовок вопроса не допускает разночтения.
- Дано изображение  и код иконки
- Задан чёткий сценарий анимации.
- Дан перечень меток, по которым автор конкурса хотел бы получить
  варианты ответа.

Допустим, автор конкурса немного знает анимацию SVG и хотел бы увидеть для освоения и саморазвития аналогичные варианты анимации CSS, Javascript, canvas, webgl.
Ведь аналогичные методы и приемы выполнения анимации взаимно дополняют друг друга.

В ответе  могут быть решения, как по одной метке, так и в комплексном использовании меток. (Будет и SVG и CSS и JS).
Автору важен результат, чёткое выполнение сценария анимации.

**Вот это строгое выполнение сценария анимации и нужно рассматривать, как вопрос, на который может быть дан однозначный ответ.**
А как внутри будет реализовано выполнение *конкретного пункта сценария*, отдается на откуп отвечающему.
Автор вопроса также может добавить дополнительные конкретные условия:

1. При наведении курсора анимация начинается в прямом направлении при уводе курсора в обратном направлении.
2. Тоже самое условие может  быть оговорено при первом и повтором клике.
3. Анимация после запуска бесконечно повторяется, пока не уведен курсор и т.д
4. Анимация после запуска бесконечно повторяется, пока не обновлена страница документа.
5. Анимация длится 4 секунды.
   Предполагаю, что таких конкретных требований к оформлению вопроса, вполне достаточно, чтобы полностью соответствовать правилам проведения конкурса.

Условия выбора победителя конкурса очевидны, - побеждает та работа, которая наиболее точно выполнит все условия конкурса.

**Ответ**: конкурсный вопрос, на мой взгляд,  не нарушает правила.

---

### Выбор победителя конкурса

Из всех поступивших работ от участников конкурса, посетителям топика, наиболее понравился вот этот [**ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086216/28748)  Но  автор  выполнил только половину пунктов сценария.
Мне тоже очень понравился этот ответ, но к сожалению, условия конкурса были выполнены не полностью  и работа не рассматривалась, как кандидат на победу.

Из оставшихся ответов, четыре работы наиболее полно выполнили условия конкурсного задания.
Но победить может быть  только один и выбирать его предстоит организатору конкурса.

Может быть выбран не самый сильный и яркий ответ, но выбирается тот ответ, который в большей степени подошёл автору.

Как я понял, [**выбранный ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086439/28748) тоже понравился остальным участникам и особых обид и разочарований не было.

### Предлагаю:

Рассмотреть такие конкретные требования к проведению текущих конкурсов анимаций, которые уточняют, но не противоречат **слишком общим** правилам проведения конкурсов SO.
Если сообщество проголосует за такой вариант решения проблемы анимационных конкурсов, то надеюсь исчезнет взаимное непонимание и бесконечные разбирательства о правомерности проведения таких анимационных конкурсов.

### Update

Комментарии из [чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56233843#56233843) от **@yolosora**

> Ответ @Alexandr_TT с примером регламента конкурсов мне в целом
> нравится, но он не решает потенциальной проблемы которую я описал в
> комментарии к ответу A K. ( в теории может появится пользователь
> который каждый день будет флудить десятками вопросов вида "анимируйте
> буквы, трусы, самолет, бубенцы" и с этим уже ничего не сделаешь) Можно
> конечно не заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией регламента,
> понадеяться на адекватность комьюнити и в случае чего вернуться к
> обсуждению модификаций уже существующего регламента. Будет хотя бы от
> чего отталкиваться.

Перечень тем всегда можно оговорить, или по крупному - анимация элементов frontend. Или более подробно: иконки, меню, анимация веб страниц, модальных окон, текста, прокрутки страниц, прорисовка маршрутов на карте и т.д
Эти темы очень востребованы и актуальны при разработке и оформлении веб приложений

Давайте заодно, чтобы не откладывать в долгий ящик, обсудим и перечень допустим тем для конкурсов анимации.

Comment: Очень конструктивное предложение, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Я вот  так понимаю, что с участниками ставящими минусы невозможно будет в принципе найти компромисс? . Запретить конкурсы анимаций и всё?  Позицию одного я по крайней мере понимаю, но не разделяю. Когда на мой прямой вопрос к нему в главном чате, я сказал: **"Так проведи мастер-класс по конкурсам анимации"** На что получил ответ: **"Конкурсы не люблю, была бы моя воля, запретил бы вовсе"**  Так может быть пора сбросить маски.  Наверное нужно прекратить доверять его мнению, его аргументации, если человек просто не любит конкурсы?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не принимайте все так близко к сердцу, всегда кто-то будет против, и это нормально. Его аргументы не стоит отметать, но и переубедить врядли получится. Считайте это вопросом веры. Жить то нам всем вместе, на этом геоиде.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Закрываем такие вопросы, авторов в пытошные подвалы

Довольно-таки серьёзно сказано.

> ...не хочу шунтировать мнение народа своим ромбиком и тяжелой
> репутацией.

А это:

> 2. Пусть такие вопросы будут - всем будет весело.

...это разве не шунтирование? Или просто красноречиво сказано?

А почему собственно должно быть весело? Потому что однажды [так сказал @VictorVosMottor](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10375/377637)? Но вот я почему-то веселья здесь в упор не вижу.

Но даже если и допустить в этом какую-то долю веселья, то обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, что [в том топике](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/377637) рейтинг ответа @VictorVosMottor выше всех остальных (ну это если не брать во внимание ответ Николая, который понимается каждым по-своему). Что же получается? Хотим мы этого или нет, нравится нам это или нет, но факт остается фактом. Для большинства это просто весело. Однако я веселья никакого в этом не вижу. Хотя бы только потому, что для меня это как минимум личное время, затраченное на то, чтобы, к моему большому сожалению, одним, как оказалось, было весело, а у других пропал спокойный сон.

Всем успехов!

Comment: Мне кажется, вы слишком **буквально** прочитали пункты 1 и 2.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, как написано, так и прочитал. Или существует ещё какой-то неизвестный мне метод чтения?

Comment: Вы прекрасно понимаете, что я хотел сказать. На сим откланиваюсь.

Comment: @AntonMenshov соглашусь с Sevastopol-ем, но немного с другой стороны - модератор (не)намеренно обозначил только 2 решения и поляризировал их, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, мой ответ. Что вы думаете на счет того, чтобы делиться опытом в формате конкретных проблем и их решения?

Comment: @eanmos: пока к новичкам применяется "be nice", а для активных участников "kick ass" - ни о какой конкретике не может идти речь. Конкурсы оказывается виноваты...

Comment: @eanmos, например я вот думаю, что кто-то работает (размещает на SO интересные работы, вопросы, ответы) и таких большинство, а кто-то устраивает бесконечные холивары. Больше как-то смахивает на обычную человеческую зависть у некоторых так называемых "борцов за справедливость".

Comment: @UModeL не вижу ни малейшей связи между соответствием "конкурсных" вопросов правилам (правила вообще тоже можно менять) и вашими утверждениями. Так можно на любую ситуацию применять ваш аргумент.

Comment: @AntonMenshov: ок. Лично Вам, чем мешают подобные "конкурсные" вопросы-ответы?

Comment: Но вы так и не ответили на вопрос. Почему бы не делится знаниями в формате конкретных вопросов и ответов, как всегда и было принято на SO?

Comment: @UModeL лично я за упорядочивание. Я вижу конфликт, которые длится довольно долго и довольно рьяно. Путем согласия о правилах и следование им можно его разрешить. Я, пожалуй, против полного запрещения таких вопросов. Однако, я прекрасно понимаю, почему некоторые из них в настоящем виде вызывают недовольство. Значит нужно что-то делать. Благо, даже "правовая основа" для этого имеется.

Comment: @AntonMenshov: Вы уклоняетесь от ответа. Эти "конкурсы" возникают раз в 3-4 месяца - это часто? Как конкретно они мешают: тормозят работу сайта, площадка заваливает Вас уведомлениями, в личку стучатся участники с просьбой поддержать? Что из перечисленного?

Comment: @UModeL я вообще не уклонялся от ответа. мне мешает конфликт, а не конкурсы, что я довольно четко выразил. Решение конфликта путем закрывания глаз ничего не дало. Значит нужно (и возможно стоило изначально) его решать по-другому. Как человек с опытом модерирования, я подхожу к этому вопросу не с позиции "что мне мешает", а с позиции "как сделать лучше наибольшему числу людей с минимальными компромиссами".

Comment: @AntonMenshov: значит конкурсы ни при чём, а данный конфликт является откровенным буллингом и "накидыванием на вентилятор"... Печально всё это.

Comment: @UModeL конфликт - по делу. Не знаю о каком накидывании вы. Выбранные методы в конфликте обеих сторон меня тоже печалят. Впрочем, каждый волен делать свои выводы.

Comment: `Лично Вам, чем мешают` А мне бы тут и порнография бы особо не мешала под отдельной меткой. Чтобы не переключаться на другие сайты лишний раз. Не мешает лично мне, значит можно?

Comment: Если честно я так и не понял ваше мнение. Можно четко: "Да, пусть будут!" / "Нет, ну их к черту!"? ;)

Comment: @vp_arth, порнография в РФ запрещена.

Comment: @Sevastopol', но вы так и не ответили на вопрос. Почему бы не делится знаниями в формате конкретных вопросов и ответов, как всегда и было принято на SO?

Comment: @eanmos, а почему собственно вы так решили, что я не делюсь знаниями в формате конкретных вопросов и ответов? Мне кажется, у вас ошибочное мнение.

Comment: @Sevastopol', нет, делитесь конечно, но ведь не в случае таких «вопросов-конкурсов». Я говорю только о них.

Comment: @eanmos, и в таких «вопросах-конкурсах» включительно стоят конкретные задачи/вопросы, где полностью и подробно расписаны сценарии анимации. Я и правда не понимаю, как на белое можно говорить черное. Такие выпады я расцениваю как непонятный мне принцип или человеческая зависть, одно из двух, и это я не приемлю.

Comment: @Sevastopol', но они не конкретные. Даже с тем сценарием, который вы описали в вопросе, нарисовать и анимировать знак рубля можно миллионом разных способов. Это скорее творческое, чем техническое задание, вот в чем проблема. Собственно, абсолютно разные вопросы даны на новогодний конкурс, конкурс анимации слова StackOverflow. Если бы эти конкурсы были конкретными, не было бы настолько разных ответов.

Comment: @eanmos, они очень даже конкретные, конкретнее и не придумаешь. И в сценариях всё конкретно расписано для выполнения одним конкретным способом, а не миллионом. А что касается творчества, то вся наша работа это и есть творчество. С техническим же заданием дорога не на SO, а на фриланс.

Comment: @Sevastopol', «Приветствуются исключительно **все средства и технологии** для рисования и создания эффекта анимации и трансформации **без ограничений**, а также **все способы** реализации для достижения этой цели и **по своему индивидуальному сценарию**, но с обязательным использованием символа (знака) российского рубля» — это цитата из ваше вопроса про рубль (выделение моё). Все эти «все способы», «любые средства», «свой индивидуальный сценарий» — ну как это может быть конкретным?

Comment: «Нарисуйте яблоко на JavaScript. Я вижу яблоко круглым и красным. Приветствуются любые способы рисования, главное чтобы яблоко было круглым и красным» — тоже конкретное задание? Я не вижу разницы между этим задание и заданием про рубль.

Comment: @eanmos, при этом расписан конкретный сценарий для выполнения задания. Нужно понять одно, каков бы не был конкретным вопрос, по любому отвечающий всегда сделает по-своему. Тому доказательство конкурс про рисование иконки ruSO. Сценарий был конкретный, но каждый выполнил работу по своему сценарию. И максимум голосов набрал самый отдаленный сценарий от заданного. Вот вам и результат. Задайте себе вопрос: Вы за что боретесь?

Comment: @Sevastopol', (1) нет, сценарий тоже нельзя назвать конкретным. (2) Да я просто не хочу, чтобы SO превратился в cyberforum, вот и все. Я не «конкурсоненавистник», мне нравятся конкурсы, там можно встретить интереснейшие ответы, просто… неформат они здесь, понимаете? Потому что они *неконкретные*. Интересные, но не конкретные.

Comment: @eanmos это ваше личное мнение, но это вовсе не значит, что это так. Это первое. И второе: это также ваше личное мнение. И в дополнение: ваше личное мнение вовсе не ваше, потому как читая ваши комментарии, вижу Андрея. У вас что, нет своего мнения? Уважайте себя, имейте свое личное мнение, будьте независимы от мнения других, будьте сильны. Тогда и жизнь будет казаться милее, жить станет легче и интереснее. Я верю в вас, у вас обязательно всё получится. С уважением к вам,

Comment: Я выразил вам свое личное мнение. Видимо, все эти споры из-за того, что у нас нет определения понятия «конкретный». В любом случае, все будет так, как решит большинство. Большинство выбрало решение @AK.

Answer (score -2):

Судя по сумме всех ответов,  из этого топика и других более ранних топиков, посвященных конкурсам анимаций, вырисовываются два основных мнения:

1. Запретить проведение конкурсов и закрыть уже проведенные конкурсы под формулировкой: "Как слишком общие вопросы, на которые невозможно дать конкретный ответ".
2. Второе мнение: разумно сформировать требования к оформлению вопроса в конкурсе анимаций.

По первому пункту хочется задать вопрос: **Что мы приобретем, а что потеряем при запрещении конкурсов анимаций?**

### Приобретем:

Улучшим базу знаний, закрыв 3-5 топиков конкурсных анимаций, и всё это на фоне оставшихся незакрытыми нескольких тысяч, действительно мусорных вопросных топиков.  С заголовками, не отражающими содержания вопроса, типа: *кнопка, окно, анимация "лагает" или сделать как на том сайте..* Со скриншотами кода в вопросе и парой маловразумительных  предложений без попыток решения.

### Потеряем:

Если SO коммерческая в итоге организация и ей не наплевать на SEO, то в будущем, при запрете анимационных Новогодних топиков, не будет  этих 1-3K просмотров   в течение первых 3 дней, к тому же  с большим временем пребывания на одной странице.

Потеряем мощный стимул для создания нетривиальных анимаций, которые требуют больших усилий, знаний, но и одновременно приносит радость творчества, позитив и одновременно ведут к быстрому профессиональному росту.

На таких конкурсах, как правило, открываются новые имена, с очень яркими работами.

Посмотрите эти работы (сразу оговорюсь не мои :)  [Misha Saidov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924501/28748) Stranger in the Q [салют](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1061155/28748) и [фейерверки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1067758/28748)  User347553  [Салют, слово, webgl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1064606/28748)

НГ, Рождество это единственный праздник, которые большинство  любят и который всех, хоть ненадолго объединяет.

На enSO это понимают и тоже стараются его встретить, как-то неординарно. Новогодние шапки, конкурс вышивки крестиком. Нет ограничений, что вот так и никак иначе, каждый рисует, что хочет, требование одно, чтобы сюжет и персонажи были новогодними.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На enSO рисуют крестиком, мы делаем праздничные анимации, какая в принципе разница?

**Коллеги, решайте, так больше пользы или вреда от закрытия конкурсов НГ?**
По крайней мере ясно сейчас, что их невозможно исправить, подогнать под существующие правила проведения конкурсов.
Почему, я уже [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9997/28748) обосновывал

Comment: «оставшихся незакрытыми нескольких тысяч, действительно мусорных вопросных топиков» — вам кто-то запрещает голосовать за их закрытие? У Sevastopol' кстати таких вопросов тоже немало.

Comment: «Новогодние шапки, конкурс вышивки крестиком» были реализованы полностью отдельно от базы знаний.

Comment: А ещё к примеру были [первоапрельские вопросы](http://web.archive.org/web/20170403175311/http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647023/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), которые спустя некоторое время после этого самого 1 апреля заботливо сносились, а не оставались висеть замусоривать базу знаний. Почему для псевдоконкурсов должно быть сделано исключение — непонятно.