# Нужно ли анимацию объекта делить на несколько простыx составляющиx анимаций?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

**Необходимость задать подобный вопрос возникла в связи с появлением таких мнений:**

[Цитата из поста с предложениями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11099/28748) @eanmos

> В качестве решения предлагаю такой вариант: нужно разбить все вопросы
> про анимацию на отдельные, конкретные составные вопросы и написать для
> них отдельные, конкретные ответы†. Каждый такой вопрос/ответ будут
> решать отдельную, конкретную проблему. Отдельную и конкретную.

@andreymal [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11097/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F/11099#comment46956_11099) к этому же посту

> «нужно разбить все вопросы про анимацию на отдельные, конкретные
> составные вопросы» — а я про это ещё полгода назад говорил, да.

Мне хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества и разобрать предложение на конкретном примере.

Вот один из проведенных конкурсов  [по анимации иконки Stackoverflow.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748)

***Сценарий анимации предложенный в вопросе:***

1. Рисование контура корзины
2. Заполнение цветом контура
3. Последовательное появление 5-ти цветных полосок
4. Исчезновение полосок в обратном порядке.
5. Зацикливание появления, исчезновения цветных полосок.

Итоговая анимация по этому сценарию:

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
  <path class="st0"  d="M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z" stroke-dasharray="0,123.5 0,123.5" stroke-dashoffset="150"> 
        <!--1. Анимация рисования контура корзины -->
     <animate id="bask" attributename="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0,123.5 0,123.5;0,0,247,0" fill="freeze" />  
         <!-- 2. Заполнение цветом корзины -->
       <animate id="bask_fill"  attributename="fill" dur="1s" begin="bask.end" values="white;#BCBBBB" fill="freeze" />
  </path>   
   
  
    <path class="st1"  d="M38 86H76.6V78.3H38V86Z"> 
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления первой цветной полоски -->
           <!-- 5. Зацикливание появления, исчезновения полосок `begin="bask_fill.end;Back5.end+1.5s` -->
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="bask_fill.end;Back5.end+1.5s" fill="freeze" /> 
            <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения первой цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back1" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back2.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>   
  <path class="st1" d="M38.8 68.4L76.6 76.3 78.2 68.7 40.4 60.8 38.8 68.4Z" >
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления второй цветной полоски -->
       <animate id="an2" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="an1.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />     <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения второй цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back2" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back3.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>     
    <path class="st1" d="M43.8 50.4L78.8 66.7 82 59.7 47 43.3 43.8 50.4Z" >
       <animate id="an3" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="an2.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
         <animate id="Back3" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back4.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>   
    
  <path class="st1"  d="M53.5 33.2L83.2 57.9 88.1 52 58.4 27.3 53.5 33.2Z" >
      <animate id="an4" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="an3.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate id="Back4" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back5.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  
  <path class="st1"  d="M72.7 14.9L66.5 19.5 89.5 50.5 95.7 45.9 72.7 14.9Z" >
     <animate id="an5" attributeName="opacity" dur="0.001s" to="1" begin="an4.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" /> 
       <animate id="Back5" attributeName="opacity" dur="0.001s" to="0"  begin="an5.end+1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>      
    <text x="32" y="115" font-size="14px" fill="#BCBBBB" >Click me</text>  
</svg>
```

Предлагается разбить анимацию на отдельные простые анимации

**Вопрос:** Есть ли в этом смысл, когда речь идёт о самостоятельных, отдельных объектах frontend, как-то: анимация иконок, модальных окон, веб страниц, отдельных анимационных персонажей, предметов веб страниц и т.д при условии, что задан исчерпывающий сценарий в вопросе?

Comment: Не знаю, что имел в виду eanmos, но я имел в виду не то, что показано здесь. Эту анимацию иконки разбивать скорее всего не требуется, а вот [анимацию слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105132) — очень даже требуется

Comment: @andreymal, разбить по буквам? Или достаточно будет по слогам?

Comment: @Sevastopol' по разным конкретным сценариям.

Comment: @andreymal, 1.`Эту анимацию иконки разбивать скорее всего не требуется` - вот что и требовалось доказать - `скорее всего`. 2.`по разным конкретным сценариям` Ну так вам же дан ответ ниже. Неужели неубедительно?

Comment: @Sevastopol' ответ ниже разбивает один конкретный сценарий, хотя его не нужно разбивать. В вашем же псевдоконкурсе про анимацию подразумевается бесконечно много сценариев - он слишком общий и должен быть разбит или закрыт.

Comment: @andreymal, должен да не обязан. Сценарий анимации в вопросе один и он подробно расписан. Если там много букав, то это вовсе не значит, что много сценариев. И еще, в конкурсе, а не в `псевдоконкурсе`. В конкурсе - стоит это уже запомнить.

Comment: @Sevastopol' фраза **«А также по своему сценарию»** ну никак не может быть одним конкретным сценарием. Ваш псевдоконкурс — псевдоконкурс с потенциально **бесконечным** числом «своих» сценариев, который должен и обязан быть разбит или закрыт.

Comment: @andreymal, не стоит верить тому, что написано. Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на ответ @StrangerintheQ, который набрал наибольшее число голосов. `Не люблю рамки` - вот ключевые слова. И чтобы мы там с вами не писали в тексте вопроса, каждый сделает по-своему. И я с @StrangerintheQ полностью согласен.

Comment: @Sevastopol' вы опять вместо конструктивных аргументов пытаетесь давить на эмоции. Чья-то там нелюбовь — это совершенно не уважительная причина нарушать правила и ломать суть базы знаний.

Comment: @andreymal, это не эмоции, а уже общественное мнение, подтвержденное голосами.

Comment: @Sevastopol' тогда такое общественное мнение должно быть формально закреплено в правилах сайта (подтверждённым модераторами решением на Мете или чем-то подобным). На момент написания данного комментария этого не произошло — а значит эти голоса не значат ничего, так как такое мнение противоречит текущим правилам сайта.

Comment: @andreymal, из этих голосов и состоит сообщество. Уберите голоса и не будет никакого сообщества. Знаете, как в Германии мудро поступают? Дополнительные тротуары прокладывают там, где уже со временем протоптаны тропинки. Подстраиваются под людей, для их же удобства. А не против. Также и здесь. Получили результат? Убедились? Так вот и пишите свои правила, чтобы их формально закрепить, если вы считаете, что имеются какие-либо противоречия. С моей точки зрения, никаких противоречий текущим правилам сайта нет.

Comment: @Sevastopol' вам надо — вы и пишите. Вам уже несколько модераторов сообщали, что ваши псевдоконкурсы нарушают текущие правила, и если вы этого не понимаете — это уже ваши личные проблемы. Ни ваше непонимание, ни чьи-либо голоса никак не влияют на свершившийся факт нарушения правил.

Comment: @andreymal, eanmos точно не имел в виду разбивать одну анимацию на несколько составляющих анимации.

Answer (score 3):

**Итак предлагается:**

> нужно разбить все вопросы про анимацию на отдельные, конкретные
> составные вопросы и написать для них отдельные, конкретные ответы†.
> Каждый такой вопрос/ответ будут решать отдельную, конкретную проблему.
> Отдельную и конкретную.

Попробую реализовать это предложение, разбивая цельную анимацию иконки на отдельные вопросы-решения:

*Анимация начнется после клика*

**1. Рисование контура корзины**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
  <path class="st0"  d="M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z" stroke-dasharray="0,123.5 0,123.5" stroke-dashoffset="150"> 
        <!--1. Анимация рисования контура корзины -->
     <animate id="bask" attributename="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0,123.5 0,123.5;0,0,247,0" fill="freeze" />  
       
  </path>
```

**2. Заполнение цветом контура корзины**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
  <path class="st0"  d="M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z" stroke-dasharray="0,123.5 0,123.5" stroke-dashoffset="150"> 
     
         <!-- 2. Заполнение цветом корзины -->
       <animate id="bask_fill"  attributename="fill" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click" values="white;#BCBBBB" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
```

**3. Появление первой  цветной полоски**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
    
    <path class="st1"  d="M38 86H76.6V78.3H38V86Z"> 
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления первой цветной полоски -->
           <animate id="an1" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click;Back1.end" fill="freeze" /> 
            <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения первой цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back1" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="1s" begin="an1.end" fill="freeze" />
    </path>   
</svg>
```

**4. Появление второй цветной полоски**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
    
    <path class="st1"  d="M38 86H76.6V78.3H38V86Z"> 
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления первой цветной полоски -->
           
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click;Back1.end" fill="freeze" /> 
          
    </path>   
  <path class="st1" d="M38.8 68.4L76.6 76.3 78.2 68.7 40.4 60.8 38.8 68.4Z" >
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления второй цветной полоски -->
       <animate id="an2" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="1s" begin="an1.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
```

**5. Появление, исчезновение, зацикливание полосок**

Я дальше не буду разбивать на отдельные простые анимации и сделаю объединение финишных  анимаций

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
    
    <path class="st1"  d="M38 86H76.6V78.3H38V86Z"> 
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления первой цветной полоски -->
           
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click;Back1.end+0.5s" fill="freeze" /> 
            <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения первой цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back1" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.5s" begin="Back2.end" fill="freeze" />
    </path>   
  <path class="st1" d="M38.8 68.4L76.6 76.3 78.2 68.7 40.4 60.8 38.8 68.4Z" >
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления второй цветной полоски -->
       <animate id="an2" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="1s" begin="an1.end" fill="freeze" />     <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения второй цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back2" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.5s" begin="an2.end"  fill="freeze" />
  </path>
```

***Теперь для сравнения исходная, полная анимация иконки, которую разрезали, как в примерах выше, на отдельные, составляющие простые анимации.***

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 12 120 120" style="border:1px solid;">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:white; stroke:#BCBBBB; stroke-width:2;}
    .st1{fill:#f48023;opacity:0;}

  </style>
  <path class="st0"  d="M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z" stroke-dasharray="0,123.5 0,123.5" stroke-dashoffset="150"> 
        <!--1. Анимация рисования контура корзины -->
     <animate id="bask" attributename="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0,123.5 0,123.5;0,0,247,0" fill="freeze" />  
         <!-- 2. Заполнение цветом корзины -->
       <animate id="bask_fill"  attributename="fill" dur="1s" begin="bask.end" values="white;#BCBBBB" fill="freeze" />
  </path>   
   
  
    <path class="st1"  d="M38 86H76.6V78.3H38V86Z"> 
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления первой цветной полоски -->
           <!-- 5. Зацикливание появления, исчезновения полосок `begin="bask_fill.end;Back5.end+1.5s` -->
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="bask_fill.end;Back5.end+1.5s" fill="freeze" /> 
            <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения первой цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back1" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back2.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>   
  <path class="st1" d="M38.8 68.4L76.6 76.3 78.2 68.7 40.4 60.8 38.8 68.4Z" >
         <!-- 3. Анимация появления второй цветной полоски -->
       <animate id="an2" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="an1.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />     <!-- 4. Анимация исчезновения второй цветной полоски -->
         <animate id="Back2" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back3.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>     
    <path class="st1" d="M43.8 50.4L78.8 66.7 82 59.7 47 43.3 43.8 50.4Z" >
       <animate id="an3" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="an2.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
         <animate id="Back3" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back4.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>   
    
  <path class="st1"  d="M53.5 33.2L83.2 57.9 88.1 52 58.4 27.3 53.5 33.2Z" >
      <animate id="an4" attributeName="opacity" to="1" dur="0.001s" begin="an3.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate id="Back4" attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="0.001s" begin="Back5.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  
  <path class="st1"  d="M72.7 14.9L66.5 19.5 89.5 50.5 95.7 45.9 72.7 14.9Z" >
     <animate id="an5" attributeName="opacity" dur="0.001s" to="1" begin="an4.end+0.125s" fill="freeze" /> 
       <animate id="Back5" attributeName="opacity" dur="0.001s" to="0"  begin="an5.end+1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>      
    <text x="32" y="115" font-size="14px" fill="#BCBBBB" >Click me</text>  
</svg>
```

Наверное интуитивно понятно, из примеров выше, что также неконструктивно требовать разбивать на простые анимации и более сложные объекты, такие как, например анимация человека, как персонажа оформления веб страницы.
Только представьте, как будет выглядеть отдельные анимации головы, рук, ног, разведенные по разным вопросам-ответам, в отрыве от основного образа персонажа.

Comment: Вы как-то… ну **очень** своеобразно поняли мое предложение. И совсем не обратили внимание на сноску, которую я оставил. Речь не идет о том, чтобы создавать вопросы по анимации рук, ног, головы, а потом еще один — для всего вместе. Речь идет о конкретных технических проблемах: как работать с `keyframe`, как работать с `animation`, или там… с `transform`. А так это переливание из пустого в порожнее.

Comment: @eanmos ну, что вам сказать.. Просто вам надо попробовать сделать самому хоть одну анимацию, как вы предлагаете сделать, открыть конкурс и посмотреть, что из этого получится с одиночными `transform` и `keyframe`  для одиночного, простого объекта. Это будет не конкурс анимаций, а обычный ответ на обычный вопрос. Но вы ведь разместили свое предложение в топике о конкурсаx анимации, а не в других местах о текущих вопросах, так что я вас правильно понял

Comment: О том и речь. Все ответы на SO должны быть обычными ответами на обычные вопросы (ИМХО, конечно). В этом суть моего поста.

Comment: @eanmos ну я же привел пример с анимацией иконки и она не укладывается в вашу концепцию. Хочу добавить, что анимация элементов frontend является 100% онтопиком, очень востребована, посмотрите конкурсы по анимации на enSO, там не раздаются голоса, что они вредны и их нужно закрыть. Там это только приветствуется

Comment: Еще раз: моя концепция — это текущие правила SO. Да, анимация с иконкой в них не укладывается, поэтому у нас тут и имеют место все эти споры. Тот мой пост — прежде всего ответ на реплику Севастополя, в которой он говорит что делится знаниями с помощью таких конкурсов. Я предложил делится знаниями так, как всегда было принято на SO — в стиле обычных ответов на обычные вопросы. В этом мое предложение: не делать каких-то исключений для соревнований по анимации. Так что поняли вы его, все-таки, неправильно.

Comment: @eanmos скажите уж лучше прямо, - вы против анимаций frontend элементов. А укладываются они в онтопик SO или нет, решать сообществу. Как показывает практика, Enso анимации вполне укладываются в онтопик.  Если вы, лично сильно против анимаций, и они вызывают у вас какой-то негатив, то всегда же можно пройти мимо и не тратить столько усилий и времени, чтобы запретить то, что не нравится лично вам.

Comment: Нет, у меня нет никаких претензий к конкретным техническим вопросов (и не важно, анимации это или нет). Сообщество действительно решило, что таким вопросам (соревнованиям) быть. Базара ноль, как говорится, я просто высказал свое мнение (причем еще до того, как сообщество что-то решило). И я не говорил, что вопросы соревнования мне не нравятся. Короче, я спорить не хочу, свое мнение высказал, а объяснять что-то в десятый раз не очень хочется. Если хотите, можете прочитать мои сообщения более внимательно, тогда вы его [мнение] поймете.

Comment: @eanmos Я очень внимательно всё читаю, что касается атак на конкурсы анимации и делаю выводы... Чтобы не быть голословным насчет анимаций на enSO и их онтопика, вот пример моего вопроса-ответа по этой же [анимации иконки stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60327827/7394871)  Что-то я ни одного возражения, обвинения в замусоривании базы знаний не прочёл там...

Comment: Ну это же лукавство какое-то. Сравните тот вопрос, который опубликован здесь и тот, который опубликован на enSO. Первый — это соревнование, что сказано там открытым текстом. Второй: конкретная проблема «I want the colored stripes to appear one after another and after the last strip appear they should disappear in the reverse order. I did not succeed in applying rotation to solve this problem. Any help for a solution would be very appreciated».

Comment: @eanmos о чем вы, какое лукавство? Всё отличие в том, что на enSO, это было оформлено как вопрос-ответ, а на ruSO  был открыт конкурс-анимация, который кстати, тоже был сначала вопросом-ответом. Но конкурс закончился за 7 дней и в итоге остался таким же точно вопросом-ответом. Формой, которая всячески приветствуется на SO - **Делиться своими знаниями в форме вопрос - ответ**

Comment: В том и лукавство, что вы выдаете эти два вопроса за одинаковые и говорите, что «вот на enSO точно такой же вопрос всех устраивает». Хотя он *совсем* не такой.

Comment: Да, вот только «если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов». Для вопросов конкурсов **по определению** существует множество верных ответов.

Comment: @eanmos создается впечатление, что у вас кончились конкретные контраргументы, по этому конкретному топику. Вы же сами предложили, что пора кончать толочь воду в ступе или переливать из пустого в порожнее...

Comment: Я пока что не увидел ни одного вашего контраргумента на мои контраргументы. И кстати, дискуссию решили продолжить вы.

Comment: @eanmos всё это общие слова, которые понимаются по разному. Я предложил вам написать код, как вы видите решение этой анимации. Благо функционал позволяет здесь

Comment: Я искренне не понимаю зачем вы мне это предложили. Я вам сказал, что такие вопросы соревнования не соответствуют правилам SO, потому что «если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов». Для вопросов конкурсов **по определению** существует множество верных ответов. Если вам есть что возразить по этому поводу — пожалуйста. Сообщество решило расширить онтопик и разрешить такие соревнования. У меня к этому никаких вопросов нет. Что вы от меня еще хотите? :) Какие контраргументы?)

Comment: Пишу с улыбкой, если что. Правда не понимаю, о чем мы спорим)

Comment: @eanmos я хочу, чтобы вы глубже проникли в проблему, я хочу, чтобы вы из противников анимационных конкурсов перешли на нейтральную сторону. Сообщество приняло решение по соревнования типа код-гольф, но не по анимационным топикам. Что всячески подчеркивается сторонниками соревнований,  И ещё, не хотел говорить, но у меня не хватает самомнения, чтобы, что-то советовать, как нужно писать на C, С++, так как это не моя специализация. Если хотите, я могу привести примеры, опять же с enSO, где на один вопрос дано больше 20-ти ответов. **Но это никого не напрягает там**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117285/discussion-between-eanmos-and-alexandr-tt).