# Чем Stack Overflow на русском отличается от схожих сайтов с IT тематикой?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

У меня следующий вопрос: **В чём конкретные отличия Stack Overflow на русском от всех других сайтов с тематикой IT и таким же форматом?**

Вот [мнение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11124/377637) участника @avp:

> Коллеги, перестаньте заниматься самообманом с базой знаний и отстаньте
> от вопросов и ответов, которые вам не нравятся, как замусоривающие эту
> самую, несуществующую базу.
>
> Для создания настоящей базы знаний по программированию тут попросту не
> предусмотрены инструменты, позволяющие нужным образом структурировать
> накопленный объем вопросов и ответов на них.

Хотелось бы оттолкнуться от этого мнения, с которым я не могу не согласиться. И вот почему. Да, функционал системы впечатляет, не спорю. Однако, обо всем функционале знают не все. Потому что большая его часть не для обычного участника. А вот что видит обычный участник? Что видит новый участник, или участник, который совсем недавно зарегистрировался на сайте, задал пару вопросов, написал пару ответов, заработав небольшую себе репутацию? Для такого участника, а это практически всё сообщество, открывается следующая картина:

- Формат: вопросы и ответы;
- Возможность комментирования;
- Лайк/Дизлайк вопросов и ответов.

В общих чертах с точки зрения рядового пользователя открытым текстом и простым языком:

**Формат: вопросы и ответы**

Ну что можно сказать о формате? Да, это не форум. Идея faq? Да, именно. Вопрос и к нему ответ. База? Да, вопросы и ответы составляют базу данных, и это главное. Но в чем ее уникальность от любой другой базы любого другого подобного сайта? Миллионы вопросов. Но ведь они все в одной общей куче, согласитесь. Сортировка, фильтрация? А где она и как это новичку увидеть и понять? Поиск? Ну давайте попробуем. Зададим в поиске самый простой вопрос, который как правило задается одним из первых на любом собеседовании: [Разница между CSS и HTML?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20CSS%20%D0%B8%20HTML%3F) И что мы видим в результатах поиска? К сожалению, [ничего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20CSS%20%D0%B8%20HTML%3F). Просто перечень вопросов, где мы не находим нужного нам ответа. А это был самый простой вопрос. А ведь говорилось об уникальности базы, говорилось о том, что у нас должно быть как в лучших университетах страны. Да, красиво было сказано. А что для этого сделано? Мне кажется, что нет такой цели создать какую-то единую уникальную базу. И за всё это время - ничего интеллектуального, ничего уникального, а только миллион вопросов с триллионом ответов, сброшенные все в одну общую кучу. Это не база знаний. Это самая простая, как и у всех, база данных.

**Возможность комментирования**

Было бы странным, если бы такая возможность отсутствовала. Отмечать комментарий полезным? Лайк? Как показала практика, недружелюбные, или даже враждебные комментарии, также лайкают. Тогда в чем полезность такой функции? Отмечать комментарий тревогой? И снова, как уже показала практика, такие комментарии удаляются. На этом же месте появляются новые, и снова новые, и в итоге ничего не меняется. Ничего уникального в комментировании нет.

**Лайк/Дизлайк вопросов и ответов**

Да, именно Лайк/Дизлайк, а не оценка полезности. Почему? Ну а как еще охарактеризовать эту функцию? Если, например, сослаться на рейтинг вопроса или ответа, то он во внимание не берется некоторыми участниками. И это при том, что он показывает полезность или не полезность, на что нам указывает подсказка при наведении на треугольнички. А вот в чем тогда уникальность этой функции? Или ее полезность? Вот если бы, например, ввести обязательное комментирование при нажатии на треугольник, которое будет объяснять то или иное действие участника, и которое будет проходить проверку модераторами, тогда да, это было бы серьезно. А пока что это просто лайк/дизлайк для школьника, и ничего уникального.

**Правила и Справки**

Очень много на страницах сайта написано различных правил, справок и советов. Хорошо, что они есть. Плохо, что не все их читают, знают, а тем более ими руководствуется. А тем более правила поведения в сообществе. Ну здесь, вероятнее всего, как говорится каждый их интерпретирует в силу своей испорченности. А что насчет самой первой страницы справки, которая открывается при регистрации каждого нового пользователя? Для чего она составлена? С целью просто показать всю серьезность сообщества таким вот образом, типа: "посмотрите как круто сделано: при регистрации открывается страница справки, да еще и с анимацией"? Думаю, что это так, просто вуаль. Потому что прокрутил ее пользователь быстро и нажал на кнопку "Продолжить", не читая. А ведь можно его легко и просто убедить добровольно принудительно, причем с удовольствием и интересом, изучить эту первую страницу. А ведь она самая первая и главная. С нее всё начинается. Но даже здесь никакой уникальности нет, поэтому и все остальные страницы правил и справок пользователям просто не интересны.

**В чём уникальность Stack Overflow на русском по сравнению со всеми другими сайтами с тематикой IT и таким же форматом?**

Это всё, что видит каждый новый пользователь. Всё, да ничего нового, ничего уникального, ничего революционного. Всё как у всех. Отсюда, кстати, вытекает и отношение его, как к уже опытным участникам сообщества, так и к самому проекту. И снова, всё как у всех. Или может быть я в другом мире живу? Так объясните же мне, пожалуйста, где и в чём уникальность Stack Overflow на русском? Только просьба, не надо воды. Конкретика, и только конкретика.

Со всем уважением ко всем участникам сообщества

Comment: _самый простой вопрос, который как правило задается одним из первых на любом собеседовании: Разница между CSS и HTML?_ - ни разу не встречал такого вопроса, поэтому не совсем корректно обобщать что **как правило**, **одним из первых**, **на любом собеседовании**

Comment: из вопроса непонятно с какими **другими** сайтами идет сравнение

Comment: *`"в чём уникальность Stack Overflow на русском?`"* -- наверное в том, что это единственный русскоязычный сайт, являющийся частью [SE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange)

Comment: @avp ещё русский язык есть :)

Comment: @Grundy, `ни разу не встречал такого вопроса` - я вам больше скажу, он еще и в методичках встречается. Странно, что вы этого не знали. Ну да ладно, это не настолько важно. `из вопроса непонятно` - а что вам непонятно? Всем понятно, только почему-то вам непонятно. Явно же не имеется ввиду сравнение с woman.ru

Comment: @Sevastopol', кому всем? _Явно же не имеется ввиду сравнение с woman.ru_ - а с чем тогда? _он еще и в методичках встречается_ - это плохие методички очевидно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy, `это плохие методички очевидно ¯\_(ツ)_/¯` - очевидно, что смайлики рисовать у вас лучше получается, чем у авторов тех самых плохих методичек.

Comment: @Sevastopol' присоединяюсь - непонятно с чем вы ruSO сравнить хотите

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы ёрничать, лучше бы правку в вопрос внесли - уже более 7 голосов вам об этом говорят )

Comment: @Kromster, от всех других. Именно от всех с тематикой IT и таким же форматом. Ну написано же предельно ясно: `в чём уникальность Stack Overflow на русском?` Почему-то Qwertiy и Barmaley прекрасно понимают вопрос. Всегда, когда готовится медиа-кит под какой-нибудь проект, в нем не сравнивают рекламируемый проект конкретно с какими-то другими сайтами, в нем пытаются отразить уникальность рекламируемого проекта в отличии от всех других.

Comment: @Sevastopol' `Именно от всех с тематикой IT и таким же форматом.` - это должно не подразумеваться, а явно прописано в вопросе.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: Спасибо за переоткрытие вопроса!

Comment: @Sevastopol', дубликат не странный. По сути все пункты в вопросе сводятся к следующему: зачем нужен ruSO, если уже есть другие похожие сайты? На этот вопрос уже даны ответы.

Comment: @Grundy, `На этот вопрос уже даны ответы.` - это ваше личное субъективное мнение. Я не спрашивал `зачем нужен ruSO, если уже есть другие похожие сайты?` Я задал вопрос `В чём уникальность Stack Overflow на русском по сравнению со всеми другими сайтами с тематикой IT и таким же форматом?` Grundy, почему вы блокируете мой вопрос?

Comment: Заметим, что два других участника, изначально подавших голоса за закрытие, в последствии подали голоса на переоткрытие вопроса после внесенных правок. Несмотря на некоторое пересечение с дубликатом, я бы все же подал голос на переоткрытие, если бы имел достаточную репутацию.

Comment: В том вопросе говориться как должно быть, а здесь - насколько это работает на самом деле, т.е. действительно ли сайт справляется лучше аналогов с задачей построения базы знаний. Думаю, лучше переоткрыть.

Comment: @Sevastopol' полагайте добрые намерения. Я думаю, просто расхождение во мнениях и\или желание улучшать качество вопросов на мете, что тоже немаловажно. Кроме того, можно было не обратить внимание, что были сделаны правки, дифференцирующие данный вопрос от дубликата. Много объяснений.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, вы правы.

Answer (score 10):

1. Популярность. Если ты хоть как-то программируешь, то уже кучу раз встречал SO в выдаче гугла. Я зарегистрировался в сети SE не на ruSO и даже не на enSO, а на codegolf. Идею уже более-менее понимаешь при пользовании, а не при регистрации.
2. QA-формат и разделение на ответы и комментарии. Сейчас таких сайтов несколько, но всё же это плюс по сравнению с форумами. Если надо найти какую-то забытую мелочь, то её просто увидеть и не надо искать среди кучи сообщений. Если ищешь что-то незнакомое, то опять же пролистывая ответы базово оцениваешь, похоже оно на то, что тебе надо или нет. И если похоже, то уже смотришь детальнее ответ и комменты к нему. Впрочем, некоторые ленятся посмотреть комменты и все ответы, но на этом я останавливаться не хочу.
3. Чистота и соответствие формату поддерживаются сообществом, а не изначальным автором. Новичок может запихнуть коммент в ответ, но его перенесут или удалят.
4. Да, внутренний поиск так себе (хотя по меткам, авторам и рейтингам ищет вполне неплохо). Но ведь есть же гугл, который всё равно в топе ссылок отправит именно сюда.
5. Качество некоторых ответов действительно хромает, но это должен оценить тот, кто их использует. У меня был случай, когда человек скопипастил кусок кода из *вопроса* и позвал меня посмотреть, что чего-то не работает. Несмотря на то, что сам вопрос был о том, что это не работает, а фикс висел в первом же ответе. То, что люди косячат - это не проблема сайта. Меня иногда и вопросы без ответов наталкивали на правильное направление в решении того, что я искал.
6. Рейтинги выражают некую условную полезность. У них есть некоторые недостатки (например, мало внимания новому ответу, когда есть уже много старых), тем не менее, в целом свою роль они как-то выполняют (как минимум, для совсем ленивых). Ну и отрицательный рейтинг - это повод задуматься, а не фигню ли написали в ответе, даже если на вид он работает. Лично у меня используется сортировка "текущие".
7. Если сомнительный ответ набирает много плюсов, то действительно ли был полезен вопрос? Если в вопрос никто не зайдёт, то неважно какие у него ответы.

Comment: Qwertiy, спасибо вам за ответ. Пусть вы и постарались выцарапать уникальность ruSO в плюшках (ну за исключением популярности, так уж сложилось), которые несложно прикрутить к любому другому сайту, но главное, что вы это сделали с любовью к сообществу, в котором мы с вами состоим. И что самое важное - честно, открыто и без всяких уколов или травли, за что я к вам всегда отношусь с особым уважением.

Answer (score 4):

В текущей формулировке, вопрос неясен.

> В чём конкретные отличия Stack Overflow на русском от других сайтов?

Каких других сайтов? enSO, Форумов, Википедий, Соц.сетей, Дискорда?

> Это всё, что видит каждый новый пользователь. Всё, да ничего нового, ничего уникального, ничего революционного. Всё как у всех.

Давайте не будем обобщать за других, а то с некоторой точки зрения, вообще все сайты одинаковые - открываешь, а там "мельтешит что-то и можно кнопочки тыкать".

> где и в чём уникальность Stack Overflow на русском?

Ровно в том, что он существует (на основе StackOverflow на английском, заметьте) и весьма в этом преуспел.

---

Любой сайт/магазин/банк/город/кофе не обязан быть уникальным, не обязан нравиться всем. Каждому своё. Оказывается, формат SO нравится достаточно большому количеству людей. Этого уже достаточно.

Comment: По сравнению с чем угодно. Почему человек должен предпочесть прийти именно сюда, а не куда-то ещё? Ну и с англоязычными тоже вполне можно сравнивать.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Лично мне лень расписывать вам то, что и так известно и от чего вы и так отмахиваетесь ) Тем более, что вы поставили такие широкие и нечеткие рамки. Флуд чистой воды.

Comment: @Qwertiy SO единственная толковая площадка, с конкретными вопросами и ответами, без тонн флуда - этого вполне достаточно чтобы сюда придти и в ответ, тратить толику времени и поддерживать здесь порядок )

Comment: @Sevastopol' а почему и для чего нужно искать плюсы и отличия?

Comment: @Эникейщик, а это разве плохо, или неправильно, или противоречит каким-то принципам или убеждениям, или что-то еще? Назовите мне, пожалуйста, причину, по которой я не могу или не должен или не имею право задать такой вопрос?

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я не получил ответа на свой вопрос, зато получил несколько встречных, заданных в мягко скажем не совсем дружелюбной форме. Не слишком ли дерзко?

Comment: @Эникейщик, никакой дерзости, абсолютно. Очевидно, вы неверно истолковали мой комментарий. У вас ни один был вопрос, а два: почему и для чего. И оба ваши вопроса мне не понятны.

Answer (score 0):

Я буду говорить не о формальном соответствии/несоответствии ruSO, остальным сообществам SO, а об ощущениях:

1. Здесь больше уровень общения/дискуссии. Если enSO все таки больше похож на базу знаний (как бы ни кривился @avp), то ruSO все таки больше дискуссионная площадка
2. Как результат п. 1 - здесь гораздо выше уровень токсичности, ну вот прямо на порядок. Давно нахожусь и тут и там и то что я вижу и то что первое бросается в глаза - токсичность. Понимаю, что по законам диалектики п.1 связан с п.2 и наоборот.
3. Достаточно высокий порог вхождения. По моим наблюдениям (цифр нет) - большинство новичков после 1-2 вопросов пропадают навсегда, лишь малая часть преодолев, токсичность опытных участников, downvoting первых вопросов кое как остаются в сообществе. Не знаю сколько из них преодолевают порог в 1000 баллов - наверное единицы.
4. Как результат п. 1, 2 и 3. ruSO теперь это дискуссионная площадка активного общения 20-30 (максимум 100) опытных юзеров.

Comment: Требуется определение токсичности. Для кого-то токсичность - это явно враждебное поведение, для кого-то - то что его вопрос закрыли из-за несоответствия правилам ресурса (также может оцениваться некоторыми участниками как враждебное поведение, но таковым не являющееся: "сейчас придут токсики и закроют вопрос"). 3 - требуется статистика, без статистики это голословное утверждение.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что я как раз то говорил об "ощущениях", а не о цифрах - ну то есть это были голословные утверждения :)

Comment: Barmaley, есть такая поговорка: `Кем себя окружаешь тем и становишься`

Comment: Нету тут токсичности. А вот на enSO - полно.

Comment: большинство новичков и не желают оставаться на руСО.Все, что им нужно - получить решение для домашки. Если повезет и вопрос не закроют, то просто сваливают молча, чтобы через некоторое время прийти уже под другим именем и с другой домашкой.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а можно так? Система разве не блокирует другие учетные записи, ip ведь как правило один.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Блокируют и по IP, но довольно мягко, насколько я знаю. Если всех подряд блокировать по подсетям IPv4, то целые города не смогут воспользоваться сайтом. Поэтому бывает плодят по нескольку учеток.