# Нестандартные подходы к решению домашки

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Я тут наткнулся на [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038600/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-javascript/1038604#1038604) с очень забавным ответом и подумал:

А почему бы не решать все подобные вопросы, таким же образом? Так сказать пускай молодые умы учатся мыслить нестандартно.

Под подобными вопросами я понимаю ну ооочень легкие вопросы и там где автор решил не разбираться в своем учебном задании. Я уверен, что этими вопросами авторы проверяют нас на нестандартные мышление.

Т.е в итоге да, автор получает  рабочее решение, где используется нестандартный подход и даже может получить похвалу от своего учителя.

Это не коим образом не противоречит:

> "Предполагайте добрые намерения"

Ведь в итоге, автор получит + несколько баллов от своего учителя за нестандартное мышление.

Это предложение не стоит трактовать, как "Давайте так делать с каждым новичком", а означает, что если задается вопрос по домашке без попыток решения, то почему бы его не решить нестандартно?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/178988

Comment: Как оказалось, обычный накрутчик :) Что только не придумают люди, ради лишних пятидесяти очков репы :)

Answer (score 13):

#### Если отбросить в сторону то, что вопрос явно задан из соображений "потроллить" , то произошло следующее:

Школьник (ребенок!) задал вопрос на Stack Overflow.

Взрослый человек "тонко потроллил" его, дав "ответ". Еще десяток взрослых людей над этим посмеялись.

Не знаю как вам, а мне бы на месте и отвечающего, и плюсовавших этот позор было бы дико стыдно.

Еще один взрослый участник считает хорошей идеей делать так вообще со всеми учебными заданиями. Этот участник нафармил на вопросах больше репутации, чем на ответах. На вопросы этого участника, включая те, которые легко нагуглить, в которых код был запощен картинкой, и в которых ехало форматирование лично я давал ответы, тратя свое личное время.

Я не понимаю, как участнику, задавшему 845 вопросов, не все из которых были идеальны, и многие из которых, если честно, сводились к "сделайте за меня", может показаться хорошей мысль так вести себя по отношению к новичкам.

#### Если не отбрасывать:

Пятиминутная задержка между "вопросом" и "ответом"? "школота" на скрине? Аватар у автора? Ответ, который как миниму упадет с той же ошибкой? Окей.

Comment: Так не предлагаю троллить новичков. Большенство, кто создает  вопросы "ПАМАГИТЕ, Я НА КОНТРОЛЬНОЙ!!" маловероятно, что зайдут сюда повторно или принесут ценность сообществу.

Comment: @iluxa1810 "маловероятно, что зайдут сюда повторно". Но могут и зайти.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, особенно после удаления вопроса как оскорбительного с автоматическим уничтожением аккаунта спрашивающего и, вероятно, баном по ip на сутки - ну прям точно прибегут спрашивать ещё раз. Но отвечать запутанным кодом нельзя. Ну-ну.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы прямо ясновидящий Уже прибежали спрашивать [Запутывание алгоритма сложения двух переменных a и b](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1041898/28748)

Answer (score 6):

1. "Предполагайте добрые намерения". Мы не можем называть такие вопросы "троллингом".
2. Не бывает плохих вопросов (с) (¬‿¬ )
3. Если такой вопрос появился, то, скорей всего, его не выдал Google. Следовательно, если на такой вопрос ответить, то людям с похожей проблемой Google выдаст этот вопрос.
4. Даже если бы это был осознанный троллинг, делать тоже самое в ответ - не самое лучше решение.
5. Я очень часто замечаю, как люди с большим опытом забывают, что в самом начале пути у нас всех были похожие "глупые вопросы". Да, возможно мы не лезли сразу в Google или специализированные сайты для вопросов и ответов (как минимум, потому что того же SO тогда ещё не было (─‿‿─)), но все люди разные.

P.S. частично "домашки" затрагиваются в недавнем обсуждении: [Нужна ли нам причина закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9704/15479)

Comment: Я подкорректировать аопрос