# Запретить оказание медвежьей услуги

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, домашки

Сейчас, как я понимаю, у учеников/студентов начинается сессия => можно увидеть много низкокачественных вопросов, где пишется задание, а потом предложение "Не знаю, как сделать" и кода, соответственно, никакого нету.

Многие пользуются случаем подфармить немного репы и отвечают, оказывая тем самым медвежью услугу, а нам же потом в будущем работать с этими недоспециалистами.

Я же предлагаю, если и отвечать на такие вопросы, то отвечать абстрактно, если не видно никаких принятых шагов к решению:

1. Отсутствует код.
2. Не описана конкретика, а написано просто:

   > не знаю, как решить
3. Нету никаких рассуждений, как, например,

   > Вот я думал сделать так, но не получилось, затем попробовал так и
   >   снова зашел в тупик...

   или

   > Вот я предполагаю решить данное задание вот так. Подскажите, на
   >   сколько мой подход будет верным для данного задания?

То есть должно быть видно, что автор делал попытки самостоятельно найти решение.

Скажем, не решение в виде готового кода, где просто нужно сделать COPY/PASTE, показать преподу и получить 5+, а алгоритм на псевдокоде. Пусть напрягут хоть какие-то извилины и накодят это.

P.S Я посмотрел свои первые вопросы, которые я задавал в студенческие годы тут и за мной, вроде, не было таких грешков. Т.е как правило я кидал задание,  а дальше свои рассуждения или код с проблемой.

Comment: Что значит "отвечать абстрактно"?

Comment: Просто, на псевдокоде, как написал в последнем предложении.

Comment: Я бы предложил сделать даже не псевдокод, а описать алгоритм. Псевдокод слишком легко.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica Тоже вариант

Comment: И каждая такая сессия будет приносит в базу знаний горы псевдокодов и водопады мыслей.

Comment: Связанные: [Нестандартные подходы к решению домашки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9713/256824)

Comment: @РустамГимранов а сейчас приносится просто "Памагите решить, я не знаю, что делать"

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать такой вопрос, влепите минус, отправьте на закрытие, если есть повод. Но выдвигать очередные извращения над плохо оформленным вопросом - не формат данного сайта.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/535/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 3):

У всех разный порог входа в программирование и разная фокусировка на проблемах. Правильные и нормальные ответы полезны ведь не только тем кто спросил, а тем кто ищет в сети. Есть возможность - добавьте студенту объяснение алгоритма. Что-то для вас элементарно, а для студента еще черный ящик с магией и пусть они знают больше - всем от этого будет лучше.
 
Помогайте с чистым сердцем, на том уровне, где вам этого действительно хочется. А студентам помогут начинающие - закрепят свои знания. Мне с этой репой что потом делать? Как ее применить "нафармленную"? Потренировал мозги, что-то вспомнил, что-то проверил - дал ответ.

Comment: Не готов создать новый вопрос на мете, поэтому спрошу тут. А как "фармить" репу-то? Или это не про git, а про wow?